# Why does COALESCE function not work for this query?

Tags: postgresql, join, subquery, coalesce

I am trying to count the number of columns that is retrieved from the subquery, and some subqueries may be empty. So instead of displaying it as an empty cell, I want it to be 0. Found out that I can do this by using the `COALESCE` function, but for example this query still gives me an empty cell:

```
CREATE VIEW third_table AS 
SELECT * 
FROM  (second_table  
NATURAL FULL JOIN (
   SELECT assignment_id, COALESCE( count(*), 0 ) AS num_60_79 
   FROM (
      SELECT assignment_id, mark_as_percent 
      FROM avg_required_table
      WHERE mark_as_percent >= 60 
      AND mark_as_percent < 80
      ) a 
   GROUP BY assignment_id
   ) b);
```

Is this how `COALESCE` is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer to question

[**`COALESCE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) would be **utterly pointless** where you placed it. The aggregate function **`count()` never returns `NULL`**. And logic dictates that `num_60_79` can never be lower than 1 in the subquery. Related:

- [Query optimization or missing indexes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33612/query-optimization-or-missing-indexes/33619#33619)

But that's irrelevant. A subquery returning **no row** cannot return any values at all.

To be precise, in your case the subquery may return any number of rows but, when joining to `second_table`, if there is no row matching on `(assignment_id, num_60_79)` then all columns from the subquery `b` are filled with `NULL` values instead. See:

- [Multiple correlated subqueries with different conditions to same table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37770396/939860)

`NATURAL FULL JOIN` is a *very exotic* way to join tables. Especially for somebody still learning how to use `COALESCE`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

> `NATURAL` is shorthand for a `USING` list that mentions all columns in
> the two tables that have the same names.

And:

> `FULL OUTER JOIN` returns all the joined rows, plus one row for each
> unmatched left-hand row (extended with nulls on the right), plus one
> row for each unmatched right-hand row (extended with nulls on the left).

I think it's safe to assume there is no column named `num_60_79` in `second_table`, and you surely wouldn't want to involve it in the join conditions if there was one. You only want to join on the column `assignment_id`, and that's what you should put in the query instead of the `NATURAL` key word.

Also, while `FULL JOIN` is theoretically possible here, we would typically see a `LEFT JOIN`.

You also don't need two layers of subqueries and some other noise in the query.

#### Proper query

All things considered, while you are ...

> trying to count the number of columns that is retrieved from the subquery

... my educated guess is you want this query instead:

```
SELECT s.*, COALESCE(b.num_60_79, 0) AS num_60_79
FROM   second_table s
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT assignment_id, count(*) AS num_60_79 
   FROM   avg_required_table
   WHERE  mark_as_percent >= 60 
   AND    mark_as_percent <  80
   GROUP  BY assignment_id
   ) b USING (assignment_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

move it to up level

more correct form:

```
SELECT 
   col1, 
   .. 
   colx, 
   COALESCE(num_60_79,0) as num_60_79,
   ... colY
   FROM (second_table 
          NATURAL FULL JOIN (SELECT assignment_id,  count(*) AS num_60_79 
                             FROM (SELECT assignment_id, mark_as_percent 
                                   FROM avg_required_table
                                   WHERE mark_as_percent >= 60 
                                   AND mark_as_percent < 80) a 
                             GROUP BY assignment_id) b);
```

and change * for list of columns, it not mean it will not work - but it more correct form also.