# Is GROUP BY select-list-ref less optimized than GROUP BY colname?

Tags: postgresql, select, group-by, functions

Just wondering if `GROUP BY 1` is slower than `GROUP BY col`?

```
SELECT x, count(x)
FROM foo
GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It demonstrably *can* be in the event `x` is not a simple column name. If it is a simple column name it doesn't matter. Take for instance this sample set.

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT now()::date AS x
  FROM generate_series(1,1e6);
```

That creates a sample set of 1,000,000 rows. Now look at the following.

```
SELECT to_char(x,'YYYY-MM-DD'), count(*)
FROM foo
GROUP BY 1;
```

The above takes `820.066 ms`, however..

```
SELECT x, count(*)
FROM foo
GROUP BY x;
```

The above takes only `190ms`, need to get it back to the preferred format? Wrap it another `SELECT`

```
SELECT to_char(x,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS x, count
FROM (
  SELECT x, count(*)
  FROM foo
  GROUP BY x
) AS t;
```

And, it still just takes 190ms. Things get even more hairy if you have an index, and useful data. Then you could perhaps be visiting a table when you wouldn't otherwise need to, or you could be sorting in seq scan when an index walk would otherwise work.

**It's important to note that this caveat on `GROUP BY #` only applies if the column of the resultset is an [injective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function). It's proof that it *can* matter, not proof that it *does* matter.**

Comment: but they are not necessarily the same, using `to_char(x,'YYYY-MM-DD')` in the outer `SELECT`, but grouping by `x` is not the same as selecting `to_char(x,'YYYY-MM-DD')` and grouping by `to_char(x,'YYYY-MM-DD')` (in many cases)

Comment: @Lamak just updated it, that was supposed to be x::date. my bad.