# Improving postgreSQL 13.3 performance on a materialised view?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, materialized-view, aggregate-filter

I found one of our APIs using this query in our materialised view which generates aggregated report on asset inventory (PostgreSQL 13.3) and is very slow on a table with 1.2 million rows

```
SELECT COALESCE (SUM(CASE
    WHEN (t1.mech_id = 222 OR t1.workshop_representation_id = 222)
        AND t1.is_incoming = true
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
    END), 0) as point1,
 COALESCE(SUM(CASE 
    WHEN (t1.mech_id = 222 OR t1.workshop_representation_id = 222)
        AND t1.is_incoming = false
        AND t1.train_id NOT IN (
                SELECT distinct t1.train_id
                FROM mvw_engine_details x1 
                WHERE x1.inspection_date BETWEEN '2022-03-01' AND '2022-06-05'
                AND (x1.mech_id = 222 OR x1.workshop_representation_id = 222) AND x1.is_incoming = true
            )
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
    END), 0) as point2,
 COALESCE(SUM(CASE
    WHEN (t1.mech_id = 222 OR t1.workshop_representation_id = 222)
        AND t1.is_incoming = true
        AND t1.express_train = 'true'
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
    END), 0) as point1express,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE 
    WHEN (t1.mech_id = 222 OR t1.workshop_representation_id = 222)
        AND t1.is_incoming = false
        AND t1.train_id NOT IN (
                SELECT distinct t1.train_id
                FROM mvw_engine_details x1 
                WHERE x1.inspection_date BETWEEN '2022-03-01' AND '2022-06-05'
                AND (x1.mech_id = 222 OR x1.workshop_representation_id = 222) AND x1.is_incoming = true
            )       
        AND t1.express_train = 'true'
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
    END), 0) as point2express
    FROM mvw_engine_details t1
    WHERE t1.inspection_date BETWEEN '2022-03-01' AND '2022-06-05'
```

[image]

After creating some index here are the current `explain analyse` stats:

> Planning Time: 0.323 ms
> Execution Time: 6.380 ms

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS mvw_transport_train_id_inspection_date 
    ON datamart.mvw_engine_details(inspection_date, train_id);


CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS mvw_transport_inspection_date_idx 
    ON datamart.mvw_engine_details (inspection_date) 
    WITH (deduplicate_items = off);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS mvw_transport_train_id_idx 
    ON datamart.mvw_engine_details (train_id) 
    WITH (deduplicate_items = off);
```

Is there any way to improve the query? or is it badly constructed?

Comment: So you consider 6 ms to be "very slow"? What would be an acceptable number? Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 2):

Your query isn't that slow. But after cleaning up, it should be a bit faster, yet:

```
WITH cte AS ( -- apply common basic filters *once*
   SELECT is_incoming, express_train, train_id
   FROM   mvw_engine_details
   WHERE  inspection_date BETWEEN '2022-03-01' AND '2022-06-05'
   AND    222 IN (mech_id, workshop_representation_id)
   )
SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE     is_incoming)                   AS point1
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE NOT is_incoming
                        AND   no_other_incoming_train)           AS point2
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE     is_incoming AND express_train) AS point1express
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE NOT is_incoming AND express_train
                        AND   no_other_incoming_train)           AS point2express
FROM  (
   SELECT is_incoming, express_train
        , NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT FROM cte c2
            WHERE  c2.train_id = c1.train_id
            AND    c2.is_incoming
            ) AS no_other_incoming_train
   FROM   cte c1
   ) sub;
```

Using a CTE, we don't have to spell out (and apply) your common filter criteria repeatedly.

About the aggregate `FILTER` clause:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27141193/939860)

Unlike `sum()`, `count()` never returns NULL. We don't need to add `COALESCE`. See:

- [Query optimization or missing indexes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33612/query-optimization-or-missing-indexes/33619#33619)

You have an "ugly OR" in the base query. See:

- [Why is an OR statement slower than UNION?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/293836/why-is-an-or-statement-slower-than-union/293851#293851)

Depending on data distribution and cardinalities, rewriting with `UNION` *might* help:

```
SELECT is_incoming, express_train, train_id
FROM   mvw_engine_details
WHERE  mech_id = 222
AND    inspection_date BETWEEN '2022-03-01' AND '2022-06-05'
UNION
SELECT is_incoming, express_train, train_id
FROM   mvw_engine_details
WHERE  workshop_representation_id = 222
AND    inspection_date BETWEEN '2022-03-01' AND '2022-06-05'
```

Unless your time range is very selective, none of your disclosed indexes is particularly useful for this. The rule of thumb is *"equality first, range later"*. See:

- [Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33196/multicolumn-index-and-performance/33220#33220)

Ideally, you have indexes on `(mech_id, inspection_date)` and `(workshop_representation_id, inspection_date)`.
If the sets from the two legs of the query are mutually exclusive, `UNION ALL` is faster, yet.