# PostgreSQL Division In Query Not Working

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, aggregate, count

So I am having a really off day or something, but for the life of me I can not figure this out. I am trying to divide `tier1` by `total` to get a percentage of the total. I thought like this:

```
(tier1 / total) as per
```

But no luck. I have CAST these as int and still nothing. I will either get an error and the query won't execute or I will get a value of 0.

Here is what I am trying to work with:

```
SELECT count(student_id) as total
,(SELECT count(fall_september_tier) FROM national_assessments.aimsweb WHERE general_outcome_measure = 'PSF' AND fall_september_tier = 1) as tier1
,(SELECT count(fall_september_tier) FROM national_assessments.aimsweb WHERE general_outcome_measure = 'PSF' AND fall_september_tier = 2) as tier2
,(SELECT count(fall_september_tier) FROM national_assessments.aimsweb WHERE general_outcome_measure = 'PSF' AND fall_september_tier = 3) as tier3
FROM national_assessments.aimsweb
WHERE general_outcome_measure = 'PSF' AND fall_september_tier IS NOT NULL
```

I had this idea as well but no luck:

```
SELECT tier1,total, tier1/total as test
FROM (
    SELECT count(student_id) as total
    ,(SELECT count(fall_september_tier) FROM national_assessments.aimsweb WHERE general_outcome_measure = 'PSF' AND fall_september_tier = 1) as tier1
    ,(SELECT count(fall_september_tier) FROM national_assessments.aimsweb WHERE general_outcome_measure = 'PSF' AND fall_september_tier = 2) as tier2
    ,(SELECT count(fall_september_tier) FROM national_assessments.aimsweb WHERE general_outcome_measure = 'PSF' AND fall_september_tier = 3) as tier3
    FROM national_assessments.aimsweb
    WHERE general_outcome_measure = 'PSF' AND fall_september_tier IS NOT NULL
) as test
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Integer division truncates fractional digits. Your expression returns a ratio between 0 and 1, which is always truncated to 0.

To get "percentage", first multiply by 100.
To also get fractional digits, cast to [**`numeric`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) (before you divide) - or multiply by `100.0`. The presence of a fractional digit in the numeric literal coerces the result to `numeric` automatically.

Typically, you would round to two fractional digits or something. Use `round()` for that (only works for `numeric`).

Adding some other basic optimizations to the query you get:

```
SELECT total
     , tier1, round((tier1 * 100.0) / total, 2) AS tier1_pct
     , tier2, round((tier2 * 100.0) / total, 2) AS tier2_pct
     , tier3, round((tier3 * 100.0) / total, 2) AS tier3_pct
FROM  (
   SELECT count(*) AS total
        , count(fall_september_tier = 1 OR NULL) AS tier1
        , count(fall_september_tier = 2 OR NULL) AS tier2
        , count(fall_september_tier = 3 OR NULL) AS tier3
   FROM   national_assessments.aimsweb
   WHERE  general_outcome_measure = 'PSF'
   AND    fall_september_tier IS NOT NULL
   ) sub;
```

Explanation for the counting technique:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)