# Delete old rows from a big table, keeping one per given time interval

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, delete, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to delete some rows from a table in which I have saved timestamps only (data type `timestamptz`):

[image]

The usual operation to delete from DB/table is very simple such as I want to delete all rows before a specific date.

```
delete from "andaz-rkugf" WHERE  snapshot_timestamp <= '2018-10-31'::date
```

But I have a different use case at the moment. I have almost 100K rows in this table, and I don't want to delete *every* row before `'2018-10-31'::date`. This is what I am trying to do in one go:

1. Select all rows before `'2018-10-31'::date`
2. Categorize them for day and hour (logically redundant).
3. Keep 1 `snapshot_timestamp` per 10 minutes and delete every other.

So in this case every hour before `'2018-10-31'::date` will just have 6 snapshot_timestamps only.

How to do this properly and fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Assumptions

- You did not declare, but the key symbol in the screenshot indicates that `snapshot_timestamp` is defined as `PRIMARY KEY`.
- There cannot be concurrent writes to involved rows.

Else you need to do more.

The best query depends on details of your setup - most importantly data distribution.

#### For *few* rows per 10-minute interval

```
WITH keep AS (
   SELECT min(snapshot_timestamp) AS snapshot_timestamp
   FROM   "andaz-rkugf"
   WHERE  snapshot_timestamp <= '2018-10-31+0'  -- ①
   GROUP  BY extract(epoch FROM snapshot_timestamp)::bigint / 600  -- ②
   )
DELETE FROM "andaz-rkugf" a
WHERE  snapshot_timestamp <= '2018-10-31+0'
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM keep k
   WHERE a.snapshot_timestamp = k.snapshot_timestamp
   );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0b6dbc7be8a20b06ff4bd0aa467dd68c)*

The CTE `keep` selects the minimum timestamp for every 10-minute interval before the given cut-off.
Notably, timestamps do not have to fall on 10-minute boundaries exactly. This query **works with *any* timestamps**.

② `extract (epoch FROM snapshot_timestamp)` extracts the number of seconds since the epoch. Cast to `bigint` and divide by 600 (seconds in a 10-minute interval). **Integer division truncates**, timestamps in the same 10-minute interval fall into the same group. Take `min()` per group (or whatever you prefer). See:

- [PostgreSQL Division In Query Not Working](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75622/postgresql-division-in-query-not-working/75628#75628)
- [Truncate timestamp to arbitrary intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12731753/939860)

The main `DELETE` removes all rows before the cut-off that aren't keepers, pinned down with `NOT EXISTS`. Related:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)

For more than a few percent of rows before the cut-off, the PK index is not going to be used at all, a sequential scan will be cheaper. But the PK index is still essential to rule out ties with duplicates.

① `'2018-10-31'` is a perfectly valid `timestamp` literal. `00:00:00` will be assumed for the missing time component. Don't cast it to `date`, that wouldn't do anything useful. Either way, without **offset**, the time zone setting of the current session is assumed. While operating with `timestamptz`, it's cleaner to declare the time zone explicitly to avoid sneaky corner-care errors. `'2018-10-31 00:00:00+0'` or `'2018-10-31+0'` for short in my example declares UTC time.

##### Large table

For **large tables** it should pay to create a temporary table with index instead of the CTE. (Maybe not for deleting a small part of "just" 100k rows.) Like:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE keep AS
SELECT min(snapshot_timestamp) AS snapshot_timestamp
FROM   "andaz-rkugf"
WHERE  snapshot_timestamp <= '2018-10-31'
GROUP  BY extract(epoch FROM snapshot_timestamp)::bigint / 600
ORDER  BY 1;

CREATE INDEX ON keep (snapshot_timestamp);
ANALYZE keep;

DELETE FROM "andaz-rkugf" a
WHERE  snapshot_timestamp <= '2018-10-31'
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM keep k
   WHERE a.snapshot_timestamp = k.snapshot_timestamp
   );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=464f8bb66489a0f2abf0580154976040)*

Run all in the same session. (Not necessarily the same transaction.)
Sufficient [`temp_buffers`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-TEMP-BUFFERS) will keep the temp table in RAM (faster).

#### For *many* rows per 10-minute interval

Meaning, the lion share is deleted. It will be faster to just delete all of them and re-insert the few "keepers":

```
WITH del AS (
   DELETE FROM "andaz-rkugf" a
   WHERE  snapshot_timestamp <= '2018-10-31'
   RETURNING *
   )
INSERT INTO "andaz-rkugf"
SELECT min(snapshot_timestamp)
FROM   del
GROUP  BY extract(epoch FROM snapshot_timestamp)::bigint / 600
ORDER  BY 1;  -- optional
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0c56b33c8ed552be605f3267796ed309)*

Answer (score 0):

You can work with `EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM snapshot_timestamp )::int % 10 != 0`.

That transforms your timestamp to simple `true`/`false` and you can index it.

With that value available you can build an index on this column and the original timestamp (or its date value to save some space).

```
CREATE INDEX help_delete ON "andaz-rkugf"(
  (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM snapshot_timestamp)::int % 10 != 0), 
  (snapshot_timestamp::date)
);

DELETE FROM "andaz-rkugf"
WHERE (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM snapshot_timestamp)::int % 10 != 0) = true
  AND snapshot_timestamp::date <= '2018-10-31'::date
```

That way the first part of the index is ref-access on all the rows with true (so all the rows that are not exact tens) ad the second part is just a range scan on date.

Example can be seen and EXPLAIN with the index usage checked at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tdWUykRtdVi19DdLxY2bRz/1

To make the index even smaller you could make it PARTIAL and filter only rows that are actually `true`.