# Join and count boolean columns by logical OR

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

There are two tables: `user_table` and `user_schedule`. Each user has four schedule rows (one for each 6 hour period per day) with one column for every workday.

The desired result is to count the number of users that are present for at least one period per day of the work week. For example, if a user is present two quarters of a day, that counts as one.

This is what I thought would work for a Monday, but it's incorrect:

```
SELECT 
 count(CASE WHEN TRUE = ANY(ARRAY_AGG(mon)) THEN 1 ELSE null END) as mon,
FROM user_table 
LEFT JOIN schedule_table ON user_table.id = schedule_table.user_id
GROUP BY user_id
```

I created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/98224/4) to demonstrate.

EDIT:

I was looking for an summary table like this

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   4 |   3 |   4 |   4 |   4 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I am running PostgreSQL 9.3

Here are the table definitions I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE user_table
(
  id integer,
  start_dt date
);


CREATE TABLE schedule_table
(
  id integer,
  user_id integer,
  mon boolean,
  tue boolean,
  wed boolean,
  thu boolean,
  fri boolean
);
```

Comment: Proper table definitions (`\d tbl` in psql) and your version of Postgres would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All users present on Monday:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id
   FROM   schedule_table 
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING bool_or(mon)
   ) s
JOIN   user_table u ON u.id = s.user_id;
```

The aggregate function [`bool_or()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) comes in handy.

Summary table:

```
SELECT count(mon OR NULL) AS mon
     , count(tue OR NULL) AS tue
     , count(wed OR NULL) AS wed
     , count(thu OR NULL) AS thu
     , count(fri OR NULL) AS fri
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id
        , bool_or(mon) AS mon
        , bool_or(tue) AS tue
        , bool_or(wed) AS wed
        , bool_or(thu) AS thu
        , bool_or(fri) AS fri
   FROM   schedule_table 
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) s;
```

Result as desired:

```
mon tue wed thu fri
4   3   4   4   4
```

Note that I didn't join to `user_table` at all here. It's not needed.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c1dee/9)

About counting techniques:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)

---

**However**, your database design is odd, `schedule_table` has no information to signify the period of the day. And why bundle attributes for the same period on all days in one row?

**Either**, to store explicit information:

```
CREATE TABLE schedule (
  schedule_id int PRIMARY KEY
, schedule text NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO schedule VALUES
  (11, 'mon, period 1')
  (12, 'mon, period 2')
  (13, 'mon, period 3')
  (14, 'mon, period 4')
  (21, 'tue, period 1')
  (22, 'tue, period 2')
  -- etc.
  ;

CREATE TABLE user_schedule (
  user_schedule_id integer,
  user_id int REFERENCES users,
  schedule_id int REFERENCES schedule
);
```

Only enter rows for periods with presence.
**Or**, to optimize storage:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, start_dt date
, presence_bitmap bit(20)
);

INSERT INTO users (start_dt, presence_bitmap) VALUES
 ('2015-02-14', '11111111111111111111'),
 ('2015-02-14', '00000000000000001111'); -- etc.
```

Only needs a fraction of the storage on disk.

Comment: Thank you. It would be difficult to change the data model at the moment, but your suggestions are much better and I wish I would have posed the question when we built the model. I think your suggestions will really help others who might face a similar design choice.

There's actually another table to label the times of the day, which are customizable for each user's organization. Too complicated, really.

Comment: @JHo: I added some more.

Comment: Wow. The `COUNT` is much faster than `SUM(CASE WHEN...)`. My query on production data went from 194ms to 119ms. Still slow but almost 40% faster.  Thanks again.

Comment: @JHo: The "summary" query has to read *the entire table*, so performance mainly depends on the size of the table (as long as the rest is optimized).