# Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, aggregate-filter

I have a Postgres database table `foo` that, among other things, has a column for `score` that ranges from 0 - 10. I want a query to return the total number of scores, the number of scores between 0 and 3, the number of scores between 4 and 6, and the number of scores between 7 and 10. Something like the following:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) as total,
  COUNT(
    SELECT * from foo where score between 0 and 3;
  ) as low,
  COUNT(
    SELECT * from foo where score between 4 and 6;
  ) as mid,
  COUNT(
    SELECT * from foo where score between 7 and 10;
  ) as high
FROM foo;
```

I tried this, but got an error with the `SELECT` in the `COUNT` statements. Any ideas how I can do this? I'm sure there's a super simple way in Postgres. I just can't figure out the correct terms to Google for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use conditional `SUM()` statements per column for each number range. The total can be summed by just using `SUM(1)`, assuming all of the data in the table is within one of the ranges - if not, just restrict it as with the others.

```
select sum(case when score between 0 and 3 then 1 else 0 end) as minrange,
       sum(case when score between 4 and 6 then 1 else 0 end) as midrange,
       sum(case when score between 7 and 10 then 1 else 0 end) as maxrange,
       sum(1) as total
from foo;
```

[SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/401fe/6).

Answer (score 13):

### Aggregate `FILTER` clause in Postgres 9.4+

Since Postgres 9.4 there is a clean and fast (SQL standard) way:

```
SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE score BETWEEN 0 AND 3)  AS low
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE score BETWEEN 4 AND 7)  AS mid
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE score BETWEEN 8 AND 10) AS high
     , count(*)                                       AS total
FROM   foo;
```

`total` adds up `low`, `mid` and `high`, unless NULL or other values are involved.

Links:

- [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)
- [Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.4#Aggregate_FILTER_clause)
- [Depesz blog post](https://www.depesz.com/2013/07/23/waiting-for-9-4-implement-the-filter-clause-for-aggregate-function-calls/)

Also read below.

### Postgres 9.3-

There are a couple of techniques:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)

[@Phil](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/93514/3684) provided a common alternative with a `CASE` statement (except for `sum(1)`, which isn't the standard way). I like to use a shorter form:

```
SELECT count(score BETWEEN 0 AND 3  OR NULL) AS low
     , count(score BETWEEN 4 AND 6  OR NULL) AS mid
     , count(score BETWEEN 7 AND 10 OR NULL) AS high
     , count(*)                              AS total
FROM   foo;
```

If your values are as defined in your question (only `0` - `10` possible), simplify further:

```
SELECT count(score < 4 OR NULL)             AS low
     , count(score BETWEEN 4 AND 6 OR NULL) AS mid
     , count(score > 6 OR NULL)             AS high
     , count(*)                             AS total
FROM   foo;
```

A bit shorter, barely faster.

#### Subtle differences

There are **subtle differences** when compared to `sum()` in [Phil's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/93514/3684):

- Most importantly, [per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

> It should be noted that except for `count`, these functions return a
> null value when no rows are selected. In particular, `sum` of no rows
> returns null, not zero as one might expect, ...

- `count(*)` *is* the standard way and a bit faster than `sum(1)`. Again, null vs. 0 applies.

Either of these queries (including Phil's) counts null values for `total`. If that's not desirable, use instead:

```
count(score) AS total_not_null
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6a750f880a7ce90c6bbcd080504c0d3c)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/355cd/5) (pg 9.3)</sub>