# How to get max sequence of rows?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with statistic of games which has next rows (I only write about rows that has interest in this context):

```
id        BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
date      TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
status    VARCHAR  -- 'WON' or 'LOSE'
player_id BIGINT   -- FOREIGN KEY
```

I need to write a query that select number of **consecutive** win games (`status = 'WON'`) by some user (`user_id = %some id%`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A case for [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT count(*) As longest_streak
FROM  (
   SELECT row_number() OVER w
          - count(status = 'WON' OR NULL) OVER w AS grp
   FROM   game
   WHERE  player_id = 1          -- %some id%
   WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY date)
   ) sub
GROUP  BY grp
ORDER  BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

Or use the aggregate `FILTER` clause in Postgres 9.4 or later:

```
... 
   SELECT row_number() OVER w
          - count(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'WON') OVER w AS grp
...
```

- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)

We count rows ordered by `date` and subtract the running number of wins. If the next row is a win, it still falls in the same group `grp`. Then get the maximum count per group.

Detailed explanation:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)