# PostgreSQL: Generate a series of dates for each group in a table

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a `balances` table in PostgreSQL 9.3 that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE balances (
  user_id INT
, balance INT
, as_of_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO balances (user_id, balance, as_of_date) VALUES
  (1, 100, '2016-01-03')
, (1,  50, '2016-01-02')
, (1,  10, '2016-01-01')
, (2, 200, '2016-01-01')
, (3,  30, '2016-01-03');
```

It only contains balances for dates that a user has made a transaction. I need it to contain a row for each user with their balance on each date in a given date range.

- If the user does not have a row for a given date in the range, I need to use their balance from the day before.
- If the user created their account after a given date in the range, I need to avoid creating a row for that user/date combination.

I can reference an `accounts` table to get users' `create_date`:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
  user_id INT
, create_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO accounts (user_id, create_date) VALUES
  (1, '2015-12-01')
, (2, '2015-12-31')
, (3, '2016-01-03');
```

My desired result looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+--------------------------+
| user_id | balance |        as_of_date        |
+---------+---------+--------------------------+
|       1 |     100 | 2016-01-03T00:00:00.000Z |
|       1 |      50 | 2016-01-02T00:00:00.000Z |
|       1 |      10 | 2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z |
|       2 |     200 | 2016-01-03T00:00:00.000Z |
|       2 |     200 | 2016-01-02T00:00:00.000Z |
|       2 |     200 | 2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z |
|       3 |      30 | 2016-01-03T00:00:00.000Z |
+---------+---------+--------------------------+
```

Note that rows have been added for user 2 for `2016-01-02` and `2016-01-03`, carrying over the previous balance from `2016-01-01`; and that no rows have been added for user 3, who was created on `2016-01-03`.

To generate a series of dates in a date range, I know I can use:

```
SELECT d.date FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2016-01-01', '2016-01-03', '1 day'::INTERVAL) d
```

...but I am struggling with `LEFT JOIN`ing that series with each set of rows grouped by `user_id`.

Comment: What about users that have their first transaction later than their `created_at`?  List them with balance 0 for those initial days? Or with NULL? Or don't list until the first transaction? Or not possible?

Comment: You are correct, a zero balance would be appropriate in that case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### 1. `CROSS JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` to subquery

```
SELECT a.user_id, COALESCE(b.balance, 0) AS balance, d.as_of_date
FROM   (
   SELECT d::date AS as_of_date  -- cast to date right away
   FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2016-01-01', '2016-01-03', interval '1 day') d
   ) d
JOIN   accounts a ON a.create_date <= d.as_of_date
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT balance
   FROM   balances
   WHERE  user_id = a.user_id
   AND    as_of_date <= d.as_of_date
   ORDER  BY as_of_date DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) b ON true
ORDER  BY a.user_id, d.as_of_date;
```

Returns your desired result - except that `as_of_date` is an actual `date`, not a `timestamp` like in your example. That should be more appropriate.

Users that are created already, but don't have any transactions, yet, are listed with a balance of 0. You did not define how to deal with the corner case.

Rather use `timestamp` input for `generate_series()`:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499873/939860)

It's crucial for performance that you back this up with a multicolumn index:

```
CREATE INDEX balances_multi_idx ON balances (user_id, as_of_date DESC, balance);
```

Very similar case on SO from just this week:

- [Aggregating the most recent joined records per week](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36170462/939860)

Find more explanation there.

#### 2. `CROSS JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` , window functions

```
SELECT user_id
     , COALESCE(max(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, grp
                                   ORDER BY as_of_date), 0) AS balance
     , as_of_date
FROM  (
   SELECT a.user_id, b.balance, d.as_of_date
        , count(b.user_id) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY as_of_date) AS grp
   FROM   (
      SELECT d::date AS as_of_date  -- cast to date right away
      FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2016-01-01', '2016-01-03', interval '1 day') d
      ) d
   JOIN   accounts a ON a.create_date <= d.as_of_date
   LEFT   JOIN balances b USING (user_id, as_of_date)
   ) sub
ORDER  BY user_id, as_of_date;
```

Same result. If you have the multicolumn index mentioned above and can get index-only scans out of it, the first solution is most probably faster.

The main feature is the running count of values to form groups. Since `count()` does not count `NULL` values, all dates without balance fall into the same group (`grp`) as the most recent balance. Then use a simple `max()` over the same window frame extended by `grp` to copy the last balance for dangling gaps.

Related:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)
- [How to get max sequence of rows?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129177/how-to-get-max-sequence-of-rows/129178#129178)

Comment: Awesome thank you. Will test it out on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

If balance is monotonic increasing something like:

```
SELECT b.user_id, max(b.balance) as balance, d.as_of_date 
FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2016-01-01', '2016-01-03', '1 day'::INTERVAL) d (as_of_date)
LEFT JOIN balances b
    on b.as_of_date <= d.as_of_date
GROUP BY b.user_id, d.as_of_date    
ORDER BY b.user_id, d.as_of_date desc
```

should do. The problem is probably a bit easier for the general case if you have access to the individual transactions instead of the balances per date.

Comment: I'm actually taking several other steps to arrive at the table in my example, which represents the end-of-day balance for each account, on each date there was a transaction. Can't count on the balance increasing over time or anything like that; think bank balances for thousands of users.