# Multiply by value from related row with latest date

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables, one with staff time entries, another with staff rates starting from a particular date:

`time_table`

```
id | staff_id | entry_date | hours
----------------------------------
1  | 1        | 15-01-2019 | 1
2  | 1        | 15-02-2019 | 2
3  | 1        | 15-03-2019 | 3
4  | 2        | 15-01-2019 | 4
5  | 2        | 15-02-2019 | 5
6  | 2        | 15-03-2019 | 6
```

`rates_table`

```
id | staff_id | start_date | rate
----------------------------------
1  | 1        | 01-01-2019 | 1
2  | 1        | 01-02-2019 | 2
3  | 1        | 01-03-2019 | 3
4  | 2        | 01-01-2019 | 4
5  | 2        | 01-02-2019 | 5
6  | 2        | 01-03-2019 | 6
```

I would like to multiply the time entries by the rate for that staff member that is the most recent, occurring on or before that time entry.

I have this query but I have no idea how to select the most recent rate that occurs before the time entry:

```
select t.staff_id, t.entry_date, t.hours * r.rate as total_rate 
from time_table t
left join rates_table r on r.staff_id = t.staff_id and r.start_date < t.entry_date;
```

https://rextester.com/DDK49143

I would like a result like the following:

```
staff_id | entry_date | total_rate
----------------------------------
1        | 15-01-2019 | 1
1        | 15-02-2019 | 4
1        | 15-03-2019 | 9
2        | 15-01-2019 | 16
2        | 15-02-2019 | 25
2        | 15-03-2019 | 36
```

How could I do this in Postgres?

Comment: You are presenting your case well. But please always start with table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements) showing data types and constraints and Postgres version. Also: what do do if *no* qualifying rate is found in `rates_table`?

Comment: Ok, will do in the future thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `LATERAL` subquery would do the job:

```
SELECT t.staff_id, t.entry_date, t.hours * r.rate AS total_rate 
FROM   time_table t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT r.rate
   FROM   rates_table r
   WHERE  r.staff_id = t.staff_id
   AND    r.start_date <= t.entry_date -- "on or before that time entry"
   ORDER  BY r.start_date DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   ) r ON true;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f0315cd9bdf029302e0ee42d10125246)*

Details depend on more information. The `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows from `time_table` in the result, even if no rate is found. (`total_rate` is NULL in that case.)

This is typically efficient for many rate entries per `staff_id` - if you have an index on `rates_table(staff_id, start_date DESC NULLS LAST)` or similar.

If you can get index-only scans out of it, a covering index would be better, yet:

```
CREATE INDEX ON rates_table (staff_id, start_date DESC NULLS LAST) INCLUDE (rate);
```

This form of the index requires Postgres 11 or later. See:

- [Can Postgres use an index-only scan for this query with joined tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190156/can-postgres-use-an-index-only-scan-for-this-query-with-joined-tables/190158#190158)

Depending on table definition, indexes, data distribution etc. other query styles may be preferable. For querying the whole table and only few rows per `staff_id`, `DISTINCT ON` might be faster ...

Related:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)
- [Slow left join lateral in subquery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230516/slow-left-join-lateral-in-subquery/230524#230524)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

Comment: Perfect, thanks for such a detailed explanation!