# Conditionally multiply by relation

Tags: postgresql

I have the following postgresql query that takes some time entries and multiplies them by the latest staff rate that occurs before that time entry. Outlined here [Multiply by value from related row with latest date](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237780/multiply-by-value-from-related-row-with-latest-date)

```sql
drop table if exists data  cascade;
create table time_table (id int, staff_id integer, entry_date date, hours numeric);
insert into time_table
values
(1, 1, to_date('15-01-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 1),
(2, 1, to_date('15-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 2),
(3, 1, to_date('15-03-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 3),
(4, 2, to_date('15-01-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 4),
(5, 2, to_date('15-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 5),
(6, 2, to_date('15-03-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 6);

create table rates_table (id int, staff_id integer, start_date date, rate numeric);
insert into rates_table
values
(1, 1, to_date('01-01-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 1),
(2, 1, to_date('01-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 2),
(3, 1, to_date('01-03-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 3),
(4, 2, to_date('01-01-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 4),
(5, 2, to_date('01-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 5),
(6, 2, to_date('01-03-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 6);

SELECT t.staff_id, t.entry_date, t.hours * r.rate AS total_rate 
FROM   time_table t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT r.rate
   FROM   rates_table r
   WHERE  r.staff_id = t.staff_id
   AND    r.start_date <= t.entry_date -- "on or before that time entry"
   ORDER  BY r.start_date DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   ) r ON true;
```

outputs:

```
staff_id | entry_date | total_rate
----------------------------------
1        | 15-01-2019 | 1
1        | 15-02-2019 | 4
1        | 15-03-2019 | 9
2        | 15-01-2019 | 16
2        | 15-02-2019 | 25
2        | 15-03-2019 | 36
```

---

I'm trying to introduce role rates, which will be used instead of the staff rate if a matching role rate exists.

That introduces a new `role_rates` table listing the rates for each role and a new `staff` table linking a staff member to a role.

I've attempted the following but I don't seem to be correctly joining the roles rates to the query.

```sql
drop table if exists data  cascade;
create table time_entries (id int, staff_id integer, entry_date date, hours numeric);
insert into time_entries
values
(1, 1, to_date('15-01-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 1),
(2, 1, to_date('15-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 2),
(3, 1, to_date('15-03-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 3),
(4, 2, to_date('15-01-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 4),
(5, 2, to_date('15-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 5),
(6, 2, to_date('15-03-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 6);

create table staff_rates (id int, staff_id integer, start_date date, rate numeric);
insert into staff_rates
values
(1, 1, to_date('01-01-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 1),
(2, 1, to_date('01-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 2),
(3, 1, to_date('01-03-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 3),
(4, 2, to_date('01-01-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 4),
(5, 2, to_date('01-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 5),
(6, 2, to_date('01-03-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 6);

create table role_rates (id int, role_id integer, start_date date, rate numeric);
insert into role_rates
values
(1, 2, to_date('01-01-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 7),
(2, 2, to_date('01-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 8),
(3, 2, to_date('01-03-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 9);

create table staff (id int, role_id integer);
insert into staff
values
(1, 1),
(2, 2);

SELECT 
    t.staff_id, 
    t.entry_date, 
    t.hours * (case when rr.rate > 0 then rr.rate else sr.rate end) AS total_rate 
FROM   time_entries t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT sr.rate
   FROM   staff_rates sr
   WHERE  sr.staff_id = t.staff_id
   AND    sr.start_date <= t.entry_date -- "on or before that time entry"
   ORDER  BY sr.start_date DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   ) sr ON true
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT staff.id, staff.role_id
   FROM   staff, staff_rates sr
   WHERE  sr.staff_id = staff.id
   LIMIT  1
   ) staff ON true
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT rr.rate
   FROM   role_rates rr, staff, staff_rates sr
   WHERE  rr.role_id = staff.role_id AND sr.staff_id = staff.id
   AND    rr.start_date <= t.entry_date -- "on or before that time entry"
   ORDER  BY rr.start_date DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   ) rr ON true;
```

How do I join the role rates table to get the following result when the new rates are introduced?

```
staff_id | entry_date | total_rate
--------------------------------------------
1        | 15-01-2019 | 1 -- uses staff rate as the staff's role has no rates
1        | 15-02-2019 | 4 -- uses staff rate as the staff's role has no rates
1        | 15-03-2019 | 9 -- uses staff rate as the staff's role has no rates
2        | 15-01-2019 | 28 -- uses role rate as the staff's role has rates
2        | 15-02-2019 | 40 -- uses role rate as the staff's role has rates
2        | 15-03-2019 | 54 -- uses role rate as the staff's role has rates
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick

```sql
SELECT 
    t.staff_id, 
    staff.role_id,
    t.entry_date, 
    t.hours * (case when rr.rate > 0 then rr.rate else sr.rate end) AS total_rate 
FROM   time_entries t, staff
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT sr.rate
   FROM   staff_rates sr
   WHERE  sr.staff_id = t.staff_id
   AND    sr.start_date <= t.entry_date -- "on or before that time entry"
   ORDER  BY sr.start_date DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   ) sr ON true
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT rr.rate
   FROM   role_rates rr, staff
   WHERE  rr.role_id = staff.role_id AND t.staff_id = staff.id
   AND    rr.start_date <= t.entry_date -- "on or before that time entry"
   ORDER  BY rr.start_date DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   ) rr ON true
WHERE  t.staff_id = staff.id
```

Comment: I am curious about the performance of this query when there is a whole year (or more) of data in time_entries.

Comment: I'll find out within the next week. Do you think it could be more performant?

Comment: i just 'hate' LATERAL', or 'OUTER APPLY' as thery are called in MS-SQL, which is probably the most important reason i have my doubts. (i am thinking about other way to do this a bit more...)

Comment: I'd love to see another solution if you come up with one

Comment: Just trying it out on 3.5M entries - it's still processing so I'm not sure how long it takes but I can tell you it's not fast.

Comment: I just cancelled the query, on my machine removing the joins and querying just the time entries and staff table takes less than 30s for 3.5M time entries. With the joins, I cancelled after 45mins - there must be a faster way.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I would do the following.

1) start with the time_entries

```
select t.id, t.staff_id, t.entry_date, t.hours 
from time_entries t;
```

2) add role_id to this query:

```
select 
  t.id, t.staff_id, t.entry_date, t.hours, 
  s.role_id 
from time_entries t 
inner join staff s on s.id=t.staff_id;
```

3) add rate:

```
select 
    t.id, 
    t.staff_id, 
    t.entry_date, 
    t.hours, 
    s.role_id,
    r.*
from time_entries t 
inner join staff s on s.id=t.staff_id
left join lateral (select rr.role_id, max(rr.rate)
    from role_rates rr
    where rr.role_id=s.role_id and rr.start_date<=t.entry_date
    group by rr.role_id) r on r.role_id = s.role_id
;
```

output of this (I did read the note of [Phil](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/5555/phil%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9), and I guessed an answer )

```
 id | staff_id | entry_date | hours | role_id | role_id | max
----+----------+------------+-------+---------+---------+-----
  1 |        1 | 2019-01-15 |     1 |       1 |         |
  2 |        1 | 2019-02-15 |     2 |       1 |         |
  3 |        1 | 2019-03-15 |     3 |       1 |         |
  4 |        2 | 2019-01-15 |     4 |       2 |       2 |   7
  5 |        2 | 2019-02-15 |     5 |       2 |       2 |   8
  6 |        2 | 2019-03-15 |     6 |       2 |       2 |   9
(6 rows)
```

I do not have rates for role 1 because I do not have values for role_id=1 in role_rates.

Comment: Thanks - it's not quite the result I was after but I figured it out in the end

Comment: I ended up using `FROM  time_entries t, staff WHERE  t.staff_id = staff.id` instead of `inner join staff s on s.id=t.staff_id` - maybe the inner join reads more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one:

```
WITH rates AS (
    select 
        sr.staff_id, 
        sr.start_date, 
        sr.rate     as StaffRate, 
        rr.rate     as RoleRate
    from staff_rates sr
    full outer join role_rates rr on rr.start_date = sr.start_date and rr.role_id = (select role_id from staff where id=sr.staff_id limit 1)
)
SELECT 
    staff_id,
    entry_date,
    hours * COALESCE(
         (SELECT r2.RoleRate FROM rates r2 WHERE r2.staff_id=te.staff_id AND r2.start_date <= te.entry_date ORDER BY r2.start_date DESC LIMIT 1), 
         (SELECT r1.StaffRate FROM rates r1 WHERE r1.staff_id=te.staff_id AND r1.start_date <= te.entry_date ORDER BY r1.start_date DESC LIMIT 1)) AS Total_rate 
FROM time_entries te
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done some tests on 300k rows. This one takes 12 mins to execute, the other query takes 7 mins. So lateral join wins this time.