# How to count multiple values of a column as one group?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-9.1, aggregate-filter

I have a table `main` with the following rows:

```
 id |  name  | rank
----+--------+------
  1 | Ali    | a
  2 | Sami   | b
  3 | Khan   | c
  4 | Kamran | d
  5 | Imran  | e
  6 | Asad   | a
  7 | Nawid  | v
  8 | Jamil  | c
  9 | Usman  | j
```

I want to count rows with certain values in column `rank`. For example, I want to group values as follows:

- Values `(a,b,v)` should come in one group by name `myvalues`.
- Values `(c,d,j)` should come in another group by name `yourvalues`.
- Value `(e)` should come to another group by name `extravalues`.

My desired result:

```
myvalues | yourvalues | extravalues
   4     |     4      |      1
```

`myvalues` counts 4 because it consists of (a,b,v). There are 2 occurrences of a, 1 occurrence of b and 1 of v - a total of 4.
The same is the case with `yourvalues` which consists of (c,d,j) and the occurrences of these values makes a total of 4.
And the last group `extravalues` consists of (e) and counts only 1 row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the aggregate `FILTER` clause in Postgres 9.4+:

```
SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE rank = ANY ('{a,b,v}')) AS myvalues
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE rank = ANY ('{c,d,j}')) AS yourvalues
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE rank = 'e')             AS extravalues
FROM main;
```

Details and alternatives for older versions:

- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)