# Finding time ranges in multiple rows

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a table with (suppose) just 2 columns:

```
- fecha (a date)
- ignicion (0/1 representing boolean state)
```

The goal is to retrieve which periods of time was ignicion held at '1', for such task I figured out an iterative approach like the one in the following queries:

```
select min(fecha) from reports.avl_historico_11557000631206 where ignicion=1  and fecha > '2016-05-11 00:00:00-03' and fecha < '2016-05-12 00:00:00-03'; 

select min(fecha) from reports.avl_historico_11557000631206 where ignicion=0  and fecha > '2016-05-11 03:01:38+00' and fecha < '2016-05-12 00:00:00-03';

select min(fecha) from reports.avl_historico_11557000631206 where ignicion=1  and fecha > '2016-05-11 03:42:19+00' and fecha < '2016-05-12 00:00:00-03';
```

Programming that is no problem, but executing it might be an issue, as the report may involve a month's wide of data, and not from just a single table being "scanned", but around 500 with the same data structure (just different table name).

Any ideas on how this could be achieved in a cleaner/better/faster way?

I've been advised on "[window](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html)" functions, but I don't really know if any of those actually fit this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be surprisingly simple with a smart application of a window function.
Based on this table definition:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl (
  fecha timestamp PRIMARY KEY
, ignicion bool NOT NULL  -- use an actual boolean!!
);
```

Query:

```
SELECT period, min(fecha), max(fecha), count(*) AS row_ct
FROM  (
   SELECT *, count(*) FILTER (WHERE NOT ignicion) OVER (ORDER BY fecha) AS period
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
WHERE  ignicion
GROUP  BY period
ORDER  BY period;
```

... combining the new aggregate `FILTER` clause (pg 9.4+) with a window function in a subquery.

- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)

The trick is to compute a running count rows with `ignicion = FALSE` in the subquery, and then group rows with `ignicion = TRUE` by that count.

If `fecha` is not unique or one of the columns can be `NULL`, you need to do more.