# Can I iterate a value depending if the previous is what I want?

Tags: postgresql, update, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Suppose that I have this table in PostgreSQL 9.4:

```
CREATE TABLE trajs ( 
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    obj_id integer,
    traj_id integer,
    geom geometry,
    t timestamp without time zone
);
```

Here is what the data looks like:

```
 obj_id, traj_id,  geom,     t
    1       1      point     '2016-04-29 09:35:00'
    1       1      point     '2016-04-29 09:40:00'
    1       1      point     '2016-04-29 09:55:00'
    2       1      point     '2016-04-29 09:35:00'
    2       1      point     '2016-04-29 09:42:00'
    2       1      point     '2016-04-29 09:50:00'
    3       1      point     '2016-04-29 09:35:00'
    3       1      point     '2016-04-29 09:41:00'
    3       1      point     '2016-04-29 09:43:00'
```

For each 'obj_id', can I iterate 'traj_id' depending on the 't' distance between the previous?

An example: for each 6 minutes of difference (between the first object with a time, like 3rd column and 1st in that table), this should be a new `traj_id` (+1) - and restart for a new `obj_id`. Here is what result should look like:

```
 obj_id, traj_id,  geom,     t
    1       1      point     '2016-04-29 09:35:00'
    1       1      point     '2016-04-29 09:40:00'
    1       2      point     '2016-04-29 09:55:00'
    2       1      point     '2016-04-29 09:35:00'
    2       2      point     '2016-04-29 09:42:00'
    2       3      point     '2016-04-29 09:50:00'
    3       1      point     '2016-04-29 09:35:00'
    3       2      point     '2016-04-29 09:41:00'
    3       2      point     '2016-04-29 09:43:00'
```

I started doing this, but my solution doesn't work. And I can't see how it can iterate by every time that the condition is met.

```
update trajs t
set traj_id = traj_id+1
where t.t > (select ant.t + interval '6 minutes' 
             from trajs ant 
             where  t.obj_id=ant.obj_id);
```

How to solve this?

Comment: It should be obvious to provide the exact table definition (complete `CREATE TABLE` statement) and your version of Postgres with a question like this. And the question is not clear to me. Clarify by adding the expected result. Your explanation sounds line `INSERT`, but your code uses `UPDATE`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I edited, hope that solved your questions. About the `UPDATE` , I was doing that way because I have to edit the traj_id column that already has values. When I said new traj_id values, I wanted to say that it have to change it, adding 1. Look to the result table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Postgres 9.4+:

```
UPDATE trajs t
SET    traj_id = upd.traj_id
FROM  (
   SELECT id, 1 + count(*) FILTER (WHERE t >= t0 + interval '6 min')
                           OVER (PARTITION BY obj_id ORDER BY t) AS traj_id
   FROM  (
      SELECT id, obj_id, t, lag(t) OVER (PARTITION BY obj_id ORDER BY t) AS t0
      FROM   trajs
      ) sub
   ) upd
WHERE t.id = upd.id
AND   t.traj_id IS DISTINCT FROM upd.traj_id;
```

Increases `traj_id` only if the previous row is 6 minutes or more earlier - exactly like requested.

About the last condition I added to optimize performance (last paragraph):

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632129/939860)

The way I formulated it, it also works for the corner case of the first row per `obj_id`, where `lag()` returns `NULL`.

About the aggregate `FILTER` I combined with the second window function:

- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works perfectly.. Do you have in mind if its possible update it comparing the actual time with the first time of a `traj_id`? Like, comparing not if the actual row is 6 minutes later than the previous, but if the actual is 6 minutes later than the first time of a new `traj_id`.

Comment: That query would be slightly different, but shouldn't be a problem. Please start a new question for your new question. you can always link to this one to provide context.