# Is there a faster way to count JSONB tags?

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan, performance, statistics, json, postgresql-performance

I'm trying to squeeze some more performance out of this query in Postgres 9.5. I'm running it over 400,000 rows.

In playing around with it, I've noticed that the `CASE` statements are adding quite a bit to the query cost - if I replace them with simply summing some existing column it halves the execution time. Is there a more efficient way to calculate these sums?

```
SELECT sum("tag1"), sum("tag2"), sum("total_tags")
FROM (
    SELECT people.data->'recruiter_id' AS recruiter_id,
          (CASE WHEN people.data->'tags' ? 'tag1' THEN 1 END) AS "tag1",
          (CASE WHEN people.data->'tags' ? 'tag2' THEN 1 END) AS "tag2", 
          ((CASE WHEN people.data->'tags' ? 'tag1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE WHEN people.data->'tags' ? 'tag2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS total_tags
    FROM people WHERE people.data->'tags' ?| ARRAY['tag1','tag2'] ) AS target
GROUP BY recruiter_id
```

Output of `EXPLAIN ANALYSE`:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=1076.30..1078.22 rows=550 width=202) (actual time=7043.115..7043.208 rows=449 loops=1)
  Group Key: (people.data -> 'recruiter_id'::text)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on people  (cost=12.85..1072.72 rows=550 width=202) (actual time=13.908..2619.878 rows=48492 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((data -> 'tags'::text) ?| '{tag1,tag2}'::text[])
        Heap Blocks: exact=26114
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_people_on_data_tags  (cost=0.00..12.82 rows=550 width=0) (actual time=9.219..9.219 rows=48493 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((data -> 'tags'::text) ?| '{tag1,tag2}'::text[])
Planning time: 0.139 ms
Execution time: 7043.291 ms
```

Running on:

> PostgreSQL 9.5.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit

The inner query and outer query are generated by separate portions of the application. Is it possible to optimise without restructuring?

Comment: The `CASE` statements themselves are a minor contributor to the cost of the query. Please add the exact definition of the table `people` and involved indexes. `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements. Are queries on `people.data->'tags'` very common? How many tags on average in `people.data`? Is `recruiter_id` an `integer` column?

Answer (score 5):

This should be faster and simpler overall:

```
SELECT *, tag1 + tag2 AS total_tags
FROM  (
   SELECT (data->>'recruiter_id')::int AS recruiter_id  -- cheaper to group by int
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE data->'tags' ? 'tag1') AS tag1
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE data->'tags' ? 'tag2') AS tag2
   FROM   people
   WHERE  data->'tags' ?| ARRAY['tag1','tag2']
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) target;
```

- Assuming that `recruiter_id` is an integer entity, it's cheaper to group by the integer value than the `jsonb` object *containing* an *integer* value. I also assume, you'd rather get the integer value in the result anyway.
- Only count once in the subquery, then add counts for the total sum in the outer `SELECT`.
- Use the aggregate `FILTER` clause for conditional counts:

  - [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)
- If you want shorter syntax, this gets you the same result and performance:

  ```
  count(data->'tags' ? 'tag1' OR NULL) AS tag1
  ```

#### Index and missing statistics for `jsonb`

Typically, **indexes** are the deciding factor for performance with big tables. But since your query retrieves 48.493 of 400.000 rows, i.e. > 12 %, the index is not helping this query *at all*.

Why the poor decision? The query planner has **no statistics** for values *inside* a `json` / `jsonb` object and has to chose the best query plans based on generic selectivity estimates. It expects to find **`rows = 550`** while the query actually finds ~ 90 x as many (**`rows=48493`**). The query plan using bitmap index scans is a poor decision. A sequential scan would be faster (not using the index at all).

The index may still be instrumental for less frequent tags (if you have those), an expression index on `data->'tags'` should serve best. Maybe even a `jsonb_path_ops` index, combined with an adapted query. More:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array)

However, for this and other reasons, while working with common tags, a plain Postgres array or a fully normalized schema will beat the performance of your `jsonb` object by a long shot.

This discussion in the postgresql-performance list is about **your problem exactly**:

- https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/54C738E1.8080405@agliodbs.com

Comment: Thanks Erwin, I appreciate the details on the explain analyse, as I'm new to reading these.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder Erwin, I've been working on another problem. I'll be testing the solutions suggested over the next couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT count("tag1"), count("tag2"), count("tag1")+count("tag2")
FROM (
    SELECT people.data->'recruiter_id' AS recruiter_id,
          nullif(people.data->'tags' ? 'tag1',false) AS "tag1",
          nullif(people.data->'tags' ? 'tag2',false) AS "tag2"
    FROM people
    ) AS target
GROUP BY recruiter_id
HAVING count("tag1")+count("tag2") > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @Dudu Markowitz answer, which I think is correct, if you are limited in how you can restructure your query, you can, at least do something like:

```
SELECT sum(tag1) AS sum_tag1, sum(tag2) AS sum_tag2, 
       /* Take out the sum("total_tags") */
       sum(tag1) +            sum(tag2) AS sum_total_tags
FROM (
    SELECT people.data->'recruiter_id' AS recruiter_id,
          (CASE WHEN people.data->'tags' ? 'tag1' THEN 1 END) AS "tag1",
          (CASE WHEN people.data->'tags' ? 'tag2' THEN 1 END) AS "tag2", 
          /* You save one CASE with two "->" */ 
    FROM people 
    WHERE people.data->'tags' ?| ARRAY['tag1','tag2'] 
     ) AS target
GROUP BY recruiter_id
```