# How to conditionally create JSON array in postgres with group by clause?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, json, postgresql-13

I am using Postgresql 13.0 and have a table category as follows:

```
 cat_id | cat_name | piece | weight | is_tag_stock
--------------------------------------------
  4     |   cat1   | 20    | 10     | true
  5     |   cat2   | 30    | 15     | false
  4     |   cat1   | 40    | 5      | false
  4     |   cat1   | 50    | 30     | false
```

How do I group by in such a way that for one category, the query yields one record, and based on is_tag_stock, it should form JSON?  Also, the JSON should contain the summation of the piece and weight field grouped by cat_id and cat_name. If is_tag_stock is true, then the piece and weight should be added to the tagged field else in the untagged field.

**NOTE:** For one cat_id, there would be only one cat_name. cat_name is included in the table just to avoid join.

### Expected Output

```
 cat_id | cat_name | tagged                      | untagged
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  4     |   cat1   | {"piece":20,"weight":10}    | {"piece":90,"weight":35}
  5     |   cat2   | {"piece":0,"weight":0}      | {"piece":30,"weight":15}
```

Comment: Please make no mistake: a `{...}` structure is not a JSON array, it's a JSON object. An array would be a list of such objects enclosed in square brackets: `[{...}, {...}, ...]`.

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation to get the sums depending on `is_tag_stock` and `jsonb_build_object()` (or `json_build_object()`) to create the encapsulating JSON.

```
SELECT cat_id,
       cat_name,
       jsonb_build_object('piece',
                          sum(CASE
                                WHEN is_tag_stock THEN
                                  piece
                              ELSE
                                0
                              END)) tagged,
       jsonb_build_object('piece',
                          sum(CASE
                                WHEN NOT is_tag_stock THEN
                                  piece
                                ELSE
                                  0
                             END)) untagged
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY cat_id,
                cat_name;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=81bbd66f41461c3736761509d3b8ce6d)

Comment: Or use the more efficient [aggregate FILTER](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/93522/3684) Like: `sum(piece) FILTER (WHERE is_tag_stock)` ...

Comment: @stickybit Thanks for answering my question. But I have a requirement for one more field i.e. weight in JSON. I have edited my question. So is there any better way to handle this as then I have to write the same CASE query for weight field as well?

Comment: @Sunny: Do not edit questions to invalidate answers. Think what you really need *before* asking the question. And show some effort. You should be able to figure this out yourself, now that I gave you the basics.

Comment: @stickybit Yes. I know how to that for the weight field. But in that case, I have to write the same CASE query two times. one for the piece and the other for weight. That's why I was asking if there is some other way!

Comment: @Sunny: Note that if you generated the aggregated results as regular columns rather than enveloping them in a JSON object, i.e. `SUM(...) AS price, SUM(...) AS weight`, you would have to repeat each conditional as well. I don't believe there's a simple way to go around that. At the very least, the problem would have nothing to do with JSON. The question would be simply how to avoid repetition of a conditional when aggregating multiple columns using the same conditional. Sounds like a legitimate question but it should be submitted separately from this one.

Comment: In the meantime, you can make your life a little easier by following the suggestion by @ErwinBrandstetter above. Not only is the FILTER syntax he suggested makes for more efficient aggregation, but it's also slightly more compact than the CASE (in this case).

Comment: @AndriyM Thanks for the suggestions.