# Aggregate query for pairs of arrays of events

Tags: postgresql, group-by, gaps-and-islands, postgresql-14

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=38322b6cb62f7a1a6a2bd63808895a37) for all of the data and queries below

I have a table `events` with the following structure:

```
create table events (
    correlation_id char(26) not null,
    user_id        bigint,
    task_id        bigint not null,
    location_id    bigint,
    type           bigint not null,
    created_at     timestamp(6) with time zone not null,
    constraint events_correlation_id_created_at_user_id_unique
        unique (correlation_id, created_at, user_id)
);
```

This table holds records of tasks being performed, that look like this:

| correlation_id | user_id | task_id | location_id | type | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01CN4HP4AN0000000000000001 | 4 | 58 | 30 | 0 | 2018-08-17 18:17:15.348629 |
| 01CN4HP4AN0000000000000001 | 4 | 58 | 30 | 1 | 2018-08-17 18:17:22.852299 |
| 01CN4HP4AN0000000000000001 | 4 | 58 | 30 | 99 | 2018-08-17 18:17:25.535593 |
| 01CN4J9SZ80000000000000003 | 4 | 97 | 30 | 0 | 2018-08-17 18:28:00.104093 |
| 01CN4J9SZ80000000000000003 | 4 | 97 | 30 | 99 | 2018-08-17 18:29:09.016840 |
| 01CN4JC1430000000000000004 | 4 | 99 | 30 | 0 | 2018-08-17 18:29:12.963264 |
| 01CN4JC1430000000000000004 | 4 | 99 | 30 | 99 | 2018-08-17 18:32:09.272632 |
| 01CN4KJCDY0000000000000005 | 139 | 97 | 30 | 0 | 2018-08-17 18:50:09.725668 |
| 01CN4KJCDY0000000000000005 | 139 | 97 | 30 | 3 | 2018-08-17 18:50:11.842000 |
| 01CN4KJCDY0000000000000005 | 139 | 97 | 30 | 99 | 2018-08-17 18:51:42.240895 |
| 01CNC4G1Y40000000000000008 | 139 | 99 | 30 | 0 | 2018-08-20 17:00:40.260430 |
| 01CNC4G1Y40000000000000008 | 139 | 99 | 30 | 99 | 2018-08-20 17:00:47.583501 |

Rows with `type = 0` indicate the start of a task, and rows with `type = 99` indicate the end of a task. (Other values mean other things that are not relevant for this question, but two example rows are included here for completeness.)

Each `task_id` corresponds to a row from a `tasks` table. The only other field in the tasks table that is relevant to this question is called `inprogress_status`, and it can be `1` or `2`, which represent `Opening task` and `Closing task` respectively.

I was originally asked for a query that would return the list of tasks, ordered by start date and location, with a single row that includes the start (`type = 0`) and end (`type = 99`) for each task.

Here is the query I used to do that:

```
SELECT e.created_at::DATE, e.location_id, e.task_id
     , CASE t.inprogress_status WHEN 2 THEN 'CLOSE' WHEN 1 THEN 'OPEN' END AS task_type
     , e.correlation_id
     , json_object_agg(e.type, json_build_object('timestamp', e.created_at, 'user_id', e.user_id)) AS events
FROM events e
JOIN tasks t on e.task_id = t.id
WHERE e.type IN (0, 99)
AND t.inprogress_status IN (1, 2)
group by created_at::DATE, location_id, task_id, correlation_id, inprogress_status
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Here is the result for that query using the data shown above:

| created_at | location_id | task_id | task_type | correlation_id | events |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-08-17 | 30 | 58 | OPEN | 01CN4HP4AN0000000000000001 | `{"0": {"timestamp": "2018-08-17T18:17:15.348629+00:00", "user_id": 4}, "99": {"timestamp": "2018-08-17T18:17:25.535593+00:00", "user_id": 4} }` |
| 2018-08-17 | 30 | 97 | CLOSE | 01CN4J9SZ80000000000000003 | `{"0": {"timestamp": "2018-08-17T18:28:00.104093+00:00", "user_id": 4}, "99": {"timestamp": "2018-08-17T18:29:09.01684+00:00", "user_id": 4} }` |
| 2018-08-17 | 30 | 99 | OPEN | 01CN4JC1430000000000000004 | `{ "0": {"timestamp": "2018-08-17T18:29:12.963264+00:00", "user_id": 4}, "99": {"timestamp": "2018-08-17T18:32:09.272632+00:00", "user_id": 4} }` |
| 2018-08-17 | 30 | 97 | CLOSE | 01CN4KJCDY0000000000000005 | `{ "0": {"timestamp": "2018-08-17T18:50:09.725668+00:00", "user_id": 139}, "99": {"timestamp": "2018-08-17T18:51:42.240895+00:00", "user_id": 139} }` |
| 2018-08-20 | 30 | 99 | OPEN | 01CNC4G1Y40000000000000008 | `{ "0": {"timestamp": "2018-08-20T17:00:40.26043+00:00", "user_id": 139}, "99" : {"timestamp": "2018-08-20T17:00:47.583501+00:00", "user_id" : 139} }` |

In the above example, `task_id` `58` and `99` have `inprogress_status = 1` and `task_id` `97` has `inprogress_status = 2`.

Now I have been asked to modify the returned data structure so that it aggregates by the `inprogress_status` as well, and returns the rows as pairs of OPEN+CLOSE events.

To try to figure out how to build this, I started by trying to get this format (the final format I actually want is below):

| created_at | location_id | events |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-08-17 | 30 | `{"OPEN": [{"correlation_id": "01CN4HP4AN0000000000000001", "0" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-17T18:17:15.348629+00:00", "user_id" : 4}, "99" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-17T18:17:25.535593+00:00", "user_id" : 4} }, {"OPEN": {"correlation_id": "01CN4JC1430000000000000004", "0" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-17T18:29:12.963264+00:00", "user_id" : 4}, "99" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-17T18:32:09.272632+00:00", "user_id" : 4} }], "CLOSE": [{"correlation_id": "01CN4J9SZ80000000000000003", "0" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-17T18:28:00.104093+00:00", "user_id" : 4}, "99" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-17T18:29:09.01684+00:00", "user_id" : 4} }, { "correlation_id": "01CN4KJCDY0000000000000005", "0" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-17T18:50:09.725668+00:00", "user_id" : 139}, "99" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-17T18:51:42.240895+00:00", "user_id" : 139} }]}` |
| 2018-08-20 | 30 | `{"OPEN": [{"correlation_id": "01CNC4G1Y40000000000000008", "0" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-20T17:00:40.26043+00:00", "user_id" : 139}, "99" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-20T17:00:47.583501+00:00", "user_id" : 139} }], "CLOSE": null}` |

Here is the first query I wrote to try to make this work:

```
WITH grouped_events AS (
    SELECT e.created_at::DATE AS created_date,
        location_id,
        task_id,
        CASE t.inprogress_status WHEN 2 THEN 'CLOSE' WHEN 1 THEN 'OPEN' END AS task_type,
        jsonb_build_object('id', e.correlation_id) ||
                jsonb_object_agg(type, jsonb_build_object('timestamp', e.created_at, 'user_id', user_id)) AS events
    FROM events e
    JOIN tasks t on e.task_id = t.id
    WHERE type IN (0, 99)
    AND inprogress_status IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY e.created_at::DATE, location_id, task_id, correlation_id, t.inprogress_status
)
SELECT created_date, location_id, json_object_agg(task_type, events)
FROM grouped_events
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

The problem is that this produces invalid JSON. with multiple identical keys:

```
{
    "OPEN": {
        "0": { "user_id": 4, "timestamp": "2018-08-17T18:29:12.963264+00:00" },
        "99": { "user_id": 4, "timestamp": "2018-08-17T18:32:09.272632+00:00" },
        "id": "01CN4JC1430000000000000004"
    },
    "OPEN": {
        "0": { "user_id": 4, "timestamp": "2018-08-17T18:17:15.348629+00:00" },
        "99": { "user_id": 4, "timestamp": "2018-08-17T18:17:25.535593+00:00" },
        "id": "01CN4HP4AN0000000000000001"
    },
    // ... etc.
}
```

I found that this query returns the data in the format show above:

```
WITH grouped_events1 AS (
    SELECT e.created_at::DATE AS created_date,
        location_id,
        task_id,
        CASE t.inprogress_status WHEN 2 THEN 'CLOSE' WHEN 1 THEN 'OPEN' END AS task_type,
        jsonb_build_object('id', e.correlation_id) ||
                jsonb_object_agg(type, jsonb_build_object('timestamp', e.created_at, 'user_id', user_id)) AS events
    FROM events e
    JOIN tasks t on e.task_id = t.id
    WHERE type IN (0, 99)
    AND inprogress_status IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY e.created_at::DATE, location_id, task_id, correlation_id, t.inprogress_status
), grouped_events2 AS (
    SELECT created_date, location_id, task_type, json_agg(events) AS events
    FROM grouped_events1
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
)
SELECT created_date, location_id, json_object_agg(task_type, events)
FROM grouped_events2
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

However, the format I actually need should just pair a single OPEN with a single CLOSE, like this (each OPEN with the CLOSE that follows it in time):

| created_at | location_id | events |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-08-17 | 30 | `{"OPEN": {"correlation_id": "01CN4HP4AN0000000000000001", "0" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-17T18:17:15.348629+00:00", "user_id" : 4}, "99" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-17T18:17:25.535593+00:00", "user_id" : 4} }, "CLOSE": {"correlation_id": "01CN4J9SZ80000000000000003", "0" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-17T18:28:00.104093+00:00", "user_id" : 4}, "99" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-17T18:29:09.01684+00:00", "user_id" : 4} }}` |
| 2018-08-17 | 30 | `{"OPEN": {"OPEN": {"correlation_id": "01CN4JC1430000000000000004", "0" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-17T18:29:12.963264+00:00", "user_id" : 4}, "99" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-17T18:32:09.272632+00:00", "user_id" : 4} }, "CLOSE": { "correlation_id": "01CN4KJCDY0000000000000005", "0" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-17T18:50:09.725668+00:00", "user_id" : 139}, "99" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-17T18:51:42.240895+00:00", "user_id" : 139} }}` |
| 2018-08-20 | 30 | `{"OPEN": [{"correlation_id": "01CNC4G1Y40000000000000008", "0" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-20T17:00:40.26043+00:00", "user_id" : 139}, "99" : {"timestamp" : "2018-08-20T17:00:47.583501+00:00", "user_id" : 139} }], "CLOSE": null}` |

Now I'm trying to figure out if I'm heading the wrong direction, because I can't see how to get to my final format from what I have.

Am I approaching this wrong? How can I get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: It would seem that each task per event is held together by the same `correlation_id` and, within, the start of a task (`type = 0`) always has `min(created_at)`, and end of task (type = 99) always `max(created_at)`. Is that so?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Correct about `correlation_id` - the ID is generated by the client when the first `events` row is inserted at the start of the task performance, and it is used for all of the events related to that performance of the task to tie them together. We cannot rely on `min(created_at)` being `type = 0` and `max(created_at)` being `type = 99`, even though that is true for all of the examples I included here. These just happened to be the samples that I had in front of me at the moment.

Comment: Two reasons `min` and `max` cannot be used to determine type: 1 - some types of tasks have other events that happen before or after the "official" start and end time of the task; 2 - if the task is still in progress there won't be a `99` yet. I can add more examples if that will help.

Comment: Your desired result indicates that after every "OPEN" event there is a "CLOSE" event. Can we rely on that and, if not, how to deal with disruptions in that pattern?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter For now we can assume that there will always be pairs of OPEN+CLOSE, with two exceptions: 1 - the first task of the day might be a CLOSE for yesterday's OPEN, in which case no OPEN will be shown; 2 - the last task of the day might be an OPEN because the corresponding CLOSE hasn't been done yet.

Comment: *"We cannot rely on `min(created_at)` being `type = 0`"* - Can we still use `min(created_at)` to determine the flow of tasks - or do we have to use `created_at` of the row with `type = 0`? Can time ranges overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces your desired result:

```
SELECT the_day, location_id
     , jsonb_object_agg(task_type, events || jsonb_build_object('correlation_id', correlation_id)) AS events
FROM  (
   SELECT e.created_at::date AS the_day, e.location_id, e.correlation_id
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE t.inprogress_status = 1)
                   OVER (PARTITION BY e.location_id ORDER BY min(e.created_at) FILTER (WHERE e.type = 0)) AS task_nr
        , CASE t.inprogress_status WHEN 2 THEN 'CLOSE' WHEN 1 THEN 'OPEN' END AS task_type     
        , jsonb_object_agg(e.type, jsonb_build_object('timestamp', e.created_at, 'user_id', e.user_id)) AS events
   FROM   events e
   JOIN   tasks t on e.task_id = t.id
   WHERE  e.type IN (0, 99)
   AND    t.inprogress_status IN (1, 2)
   GROUP  BY 1, 2, e.correlation_id, t.inprogress_status
   ) sub
GROUP  BY the_day, location_id, task_nr
ORDER  BY the_day, location_id, task_nr;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bf37fb42963787b0deecce3db4736821)*

Except that missing 'OPEN' events at the start of the day and missing 'CLOSE' events at the end are just missing.

I use `jsonb` instead of `json` to allow the [`jsonb || jsonb` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE). You can just cast the result to `json`, if you actually need that.

**Core feature** is this sophisticated expression to form task numbers:

```
    , count(*) FILTER (WHERE t.inprogress_status = 1)
               OVER (PARTITION BY e.location_id ORDER BY min(e.created_at) FILTER (WHERE e.type = 0)) AS task_nr
```

Every 'OPEN' task starts a new group. The `created_at` with `type = 0` defines the sequence of tasks. Technically, this works because we can nest aggregate function (even with the aggregate `FILTER` clause) in window functions.
Related answers:

- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)
- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied in PHP/PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242764/939860)
- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)