# Postgres Nested WHEN Aggregate Function

Tags: postgresql, subquery, aggregate, count, aggregate-filter

In PostgreSQL (version 9.4) I am trying to construct a query to determine in various tranches how many times various numbers appear in the data set between ranges. When I query group-ing by `"SettlementPointPrice"` the `count()` function works correctly bucketing prices into individual tranches as I would expect. However, this creates hundreds of rows. I am looking for the ability (sub-query?) to aggregate the sum of count()'s in each bucket into one single row. What is the best way to manage this in SQL?

I am using a statement like this (full SQL below) for each bucket/tranche:

```
CASE WHEN (round(sum("DA-A"."SettlementPointPrice"),2)) BETWEEN 0 AND 10
     THEN count(*) ELSE 0 END AS "DA $0 - $10",
```

When I group by "SettlementPointPrice" (two prices in this example) to confirm the data counts the buckets correctly. As the table below shows.

Raw data from individual two days:

```
Row | "SettlementPointPrice" | 0-10 | 11-20 | 21-30
1   | 18                     | 0    | 1     | 0
2   | 22                     | 0    | 0     | 1
```

However, I am unable to get the aggregated summation by grouping them all together. I assume this is a sub-query?

I would like the result to be as such:

```
Row | 0-10 | 11-20 | 21-30
1   | 0    | 1     | 1
```

Full SQL code:

```
SELECT
  "DA-A"."SettlementPointPrice",
  CASE WHEN (round(sum("DA-A"."SettlementPointPrice"),2)) BETWEEN 0 AND 10
       THEN count(*) ELSE 0 END AS "DA $0 - $10",
  CASE WHEN (round(sum("DA-A"."SettlementPointPrice"),2)) BETWEEN 11 AND 20
       THEN COUNT(*) ELSE 0 END AS "DA $11 - $20",
  CASE WHEN (round(sum("DA-A"."SettlementPointPrice"),2)) BETWEEN 21 AND 30
       THEN COUNT(*) ELSE 0 END AS "DA $21 - $30"
FROM 
  public.da "DA-A", 
  public.rt_aggregate "RT-A"
WHERE 
  "RT-A"."DeliveryDate" = "DA-A"."DeliveryDate" AND
  "RT-A"."SettlementPointName" = "DA-A"."SettlementPointName" AND
  "DA-A"."SettlementPointName" = 'John' AND 
  "DA-A"."DeliveryDate" >= '2015-02-01' AND
  "DA-A"."DeliveryDate" <= '2015-02-20' AND
 ("RT-A"."DeliveryHour" = 14) and 
  date_part('hour', "DA-A"."DeliveryHour") = "RT-A"."DeliveryHour"
GROUP BY
  "DA-A"."SettlementPointPrice",
  "DA-A"."SettlementPointName"
```

Comment: As *always* your version of Postgres, please. And the name is PostgreSQL or Postgres for short. Never "Postgre".

Comment: When you write `grouping them all together`, do you mean *all* selected rows, so that you get a single row aggregating *all* counts? Your column "Row" is a bit confusing, that's just noise, right? And it's unclear where the column `Source DA` in the result comes from. Does not agree with the query you show.

Comment: EB: Yes, I mean aggregating all the rows and the count values into a single value. For example say there are ten rows (ten days) I just want the summation of those ten days sum(count(*)) as an example by bucket.

Comment: EB: "Row" is just just noise, but also highlights how I am getting two rows now, but really just want one single row with everything as a sum in each bucket.

Comment: EB: Sorry, Source DA should read: "SettlementPointPrice". Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some processing this boiled down to:

While your predicate `d."SettlementPointName" = 'John'` is filtering a *single* value for "SettlementPointName" anyway, simplify to:

```
SELECT count(                                     d."SettlementPointPrice" < 10.5 OR NULL) AS da_00_10
     , count(d."SettlementPointPrice" >= 10.5 AND d."SettlementPointPrice" < 20.5 OR NULL) AS da_11_20
     , count(d."SettlementPointPrice" >= 20.5 AND d."SettlementPointPrice" < 30.5 OR NULL) AS da_21_30
FROM   public.da d
JOIN   public.rt_aggregate r USING ("DeliveryDate", "SettlementPointName")
WHERE  d."SettlementPointName" = 'John'
AND    d."DeliveryDate" >= '2015-02-01'
AND    d."DeliveryDate" <= '2015-02-20'
AND    r."DeliveryHour" = 14
AND    date_part('hour', d."DeliveryHour") = r."DeliveryHour";
```

About the counting technique:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)

Or better, yet, use the new aggregate filter technique in pg **9.4**:

```
SELECT d."SettlementPointName"
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE d."SettlementPointPrice" <  10.5) AS da_00_10
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE d."SettlementPointPrice" >= 10.5
                        AND   d."SettlementPointPrice" <  20.5) AS da_11_20
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE d."SettlementPointPrice" >= 20.5
                        AND   d."SettlementPointPrice" <  30.5) AS da_21_30
FROM   public.da d
JOIN   public.rt_aggregate r USING ("DeliveryDate", "SettlementPointName")
WHERE  d."DeliveryDate" >= '2015-02-01'
AND    d."DeliveryDate" <= '2015-02-20'
AND    r."DeliveryHour" = 14
AND    date_part('hour', d."DeliveryHour") = r."DeliveryHour"
GROUP  BY 1;
```

This time, selecting **all names** and returning one row per name like you asked in the comment.

Details for `FILTER`:

- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)

Comment: @JAS: Consider the added notes.

Comment: One additional question to your code. If remove the WHERE  d."SettlementPointName" = 'John' and want a GROUP BY  d."SettlementPointName" how is that done through the sub select?

Comment: Your question is a bit light on your actual objective. My guess is you just need the second query, where you can just add `GROUP BY d."SettlementPointName"` to get one row with counts ***per name***. No subquery.

Comment: EB: Your second update with additional SQL solved what I was looking for: