# How to select data in the same table on different rows that are empty?

Tags: postgresql, select, sqlite, count, null

I use this select on my SQLite database:

```
SELECT attributeX
 FROM table
 GROUP BY attributeX
 HAVING COUNT(attributeY) = 0;
```

My table:

```
  attributeX (type integer) |  attributeY (type text)
----------------+-------
  1452 | aaa            
  1452 | bbb
  1452 | 
  1452 | bbb
  1453 |
  1453 |   
  1453 |
  1454 | eee
  1454 | fff
  1455 | iii
      ....
```

I get result `1453` only when all items in column `attributeY` are empty for `1453`. So in SQLite I get result `1453`.

I have the same database only with `myschema` in PostgreSQL. I use this `SELECT`:

```
SELECT attributeX
 FROM myschema.table
 GROUP BY attributeX
 HAVING COUNT(attributeY) = 0;
```

and I get:

```
 attributeX
------------
(0 rows)
```

How to select in PostgreSQL?

SQLite schema of this table:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
 attribute1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 attributeX INTEGER NOT NULL,
 attribute2 TEXT NOT NULL,
 attributeY TEXT
);

CREATE INDEX table_attributeY_idx ON table (attributeY);
CREATE INDEX table_attribute2_idx ON table (attribute2);
CREATE INDEX table_attributeX_idx ON table (attributeX);
```

PostgreSQL schema of this table:

```
Table "myschema.table"
        Column  |          Type         |                                    Modifier                             | Storage  | Desc
----------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+-------
 attribute1     | integer               | not null implicitly nextval('myschema.table_attribute1_seq'::regclass)  | plain    |
 attributeX     | integer               | not null                                                                | plain    |
 attribute2     | character varying(32) | not null                                                                | extended |
 attributeY     | text                  |                                                                         | extended |
Indexy:
    "table_attribute1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (attribute1)
    "fki_table_attributeX_fkey" btree (attributeX)
Conditions for foreign key:
    "table_attributeX_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (attributeX) REFERENCES myschema.table2(attributeX2) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
Has OID: no
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO myschema.table (attributeX, attribute2, attributeY)
VALUES (%s, %s,%s)... (python script)
```

Comment: Please post a http://sqlfiddle.com/ demonstrating a self-contained test case. Per my answer, I can't see this issue hwne I test.

Comment: Self contained. Include the values. Preferably provide a http://sqlfiddle.com . something other people can run to see the same results you see.

Comment: Are you actually inserting NULL values, or empty strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You explain:

> I get result `1453` only when all items in column `attributeY` are **empty** for `1453`.

But that's incorrect. Bold emphasis mine. The aggregate function `count` returns ([per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html)):

> number of input rows for which the value of expression is not null

The same is true for SQLite ([per documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)):

> The count(X) function returns a count of the number of times that *X* is
>   not NULL in a group.

You obviously have one or more rows with a non-null value in `attributeY` in your Postgres table - probably an empty string `''`.

Test with:

```
SELECT *
FROM   myschema.table
WHERE  attributeX = 1453
AND    attributeY IS NOT NULL;
```

Be sure to understand the **difference between "empty" (`''`) and `NULL`**:

Empty strings are character types (typically `text`, `varchar` or `char`) with 0 characters (`''`) - so basically "nothing", the equivalent of `0` for a numeric data type. `NULL` is possible for *any* data type and means "unknown". Some clients have a hard time making the difference clear in their display.

#### Alternative query

To find `attributeX` where all `attributeY` are **either *empty* or *NULL*** use this alternative query:

```
SELECT attributeX
FROM   myschema.table
GROUP  BY attributeX
HAVING NOT bool_or(attributeY <> '');
```

The expression `attributeY <> ''` is only `true` for non-null, non-empty `attributeY`. The aggregate function `bool_or` returns ([per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html)):

> true if at least one input value is true, otherwise false

Those are the results we *exclude* (`NOT ...`) and return the rest. Voilá.

There are many other (less elegant) ways to achieve the same. Like:

```
... HAVING count(CASE WHEN attributeY <> '' THEN 1 END) = 0;
... HAVING count(attributeY <> '' OR NULL) = 0;
... HAVING count(NULLIF(attributeY, '') = 0;
```

More:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)
- [Replace empty strings with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10686513/939860)

Comment: That's what I thought too, and why I was pushing for proper sample data. But that doesn't explain the difference observed between SQLite and PostgreSQL. I wondered if SQLite treated `''` as `null` for the purpose of `count` but it doesn't, it correctly counts empty strings.

Comment: @CraigRinger: The difference between SQLite and PostgreSQL is rather "claimed" than "observed". If the Postgres DB has different data, then that's the extent of the difference here. Of course, a clean test case would have solved the problem to begin with - and we would have never seen it here ...

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter Thanks. When I use your select with IS NOT NULL I get correct results "1453" where attributeY is empty on all rows, but I have the same result when I use '' too. I do not understand because it does not work with HAVING COUNT? :-( Please help me...

Comment: @user41060: I added an alternative query. You need to understand the concepts of "NULL" and "empty" to avoid constant headache when working with SQL.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 2):

It works for me with a similarly created structure. You didn't provide DDL and INSERTs for your table so I just made up a shorter one that should have the same effect:

```
$ sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.8.8.3 2015-02-25 13:29:11
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test(x integer, y text);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test(x, y) VALUES (1, '');
sqlite> INSERT INTO test(x, y) VALUES (2, NULL);
sqlite> select x from test group by x having count(y) = 0;
2
```

and

```
$ psql -q regress
regress=> CREATE TABLE test(x integer, y text);
regress=> INSERT INTO test(x, y) VALUES (1, '');
regress=> INSERT INTO test(x, y) VALUES (2, NULL);
regress=> select x from test group by x having count(y) = 0;
 x 
---
 2
(1 row)
```

In both cases the results match what I would've expected.

I was initially wondering if your SQLite was treating `''` and `NULL` as equivalent, but my test above suggests that it behaves as per the standard, treating `''` as non-null for the purpose of `count`.

Comment: Thanks, I have added database structures and INSERT... I really do not get any results when I use this select...