# Extract start and end per group of rows, where only the end can be identified

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that looks like this.

```
id  date_from           date_to             description           vehicle
1   2015-10-21 08:00    2015-10-21 10:00    GARAGE TO CLIENT 1    1
2   2015-10-21 12:00    2015-10-21 13:00    CLIENT 2 TO GARAGE    1
3   2015-10-21 14:00    2015-10-21 15:00    RET GARAGE            1
4   2015-10-21 18:00    2015-10-21 19:00    GARAGE TO CLIENT 1    1
5   2015-10-21 20:00    2015-10-21 21:00    CLIENT 2 TO GARAGE    1
6   2015-10-21 21:00    2015-10-21 22:00    RET GARAGE            1
```

I need to get the total time that the vehicle is in use.
He stops being in use on first line and stops on the first description that starts with "RET".

A table like that would return

```
vehicle   starts              stops
1         2015-10-21 08:00    2015-10-21 15:00
1         2015-10-21 18:00    2015-10-21 22:00
```

Comment: Are the `date_from` and `date_to` columns ALWAYS whole hours?

Comment: Yes they are whole hours.

Comment: Also, is the `id` column actually unique for each row?

Comment: Yes, it is unique

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to make unique for the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count()` as window function to identify groups like this:

```
SELECT vehicle, min(date_from) AS starts, max(date_to) AS stops
FROM  (
   SELECT vehicle, date_from, date_to
        , count(description LIKE 'RET%' OR NULL)
             OVER (PARTITION BY vehicle ORDER BY date_from DESC) AS grp
    FROM  tbl
   ) sub
GROUP  BY vehicle, grp;
```

Count in ***descending*** order, since the *end* of each group is significant. Then just extract minimum start and maximum end per `grp` in the outer `SELECT`.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1d862/2)

Assuming all timestamp columns are defined `NOT NULL`.

Since timestamps are in ascending order (due to the logic of the problem), we don't need the `id` column at all for this.

This works for any number of vehicles, not just the one you demonstrate in your example.

Related answer with more details:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)

About my counting method `count(<expression> OR NULL)`:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)