# Find changed columns for near-identical rows across tables

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql

I run PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on Windows 7, 64-bit.

My data arrives quarterly, in multiple tables (`table1, ..., tableN`) that are linked, intra-period, by cross-table constraints based on key identifiers. Among other columns, each table has identifiers that persist over time: `pfi` - *persistent feature identifier* and `ufi` - *universal feature identifier*.

**`pfi`** is unique per table (it's exceedingly rare that `table1.pfi = table2.pfi`.
**`ufi`** is unique across all tables and across all time. It's not a hash of the row data, but you could think of it as such.

Each period, in each table, some new `pfi`are brought into being and some old `pfi` are retired. Some `pfi` change attributes. `ufi` tracks any change to *any* attribute for a given `pfi`(row), so to fetch changed (and new) rows for `table1` it's simply a matter of:

```
-- 1st query
select a.*
into vm201512.property_d
from vm201512.property a
where not exists (select 1 from vm201412.property where ufi = a.ufi);
```

This selects all rows which are either new (new `pfi`) or changed in at least one column.

About 96% of each table remains unchanged in every respect. Accordingly, in analysing the cross-period changes I build a table that only includes changed and new data. This reduces the table size from ~3.5m rows to ~225k rows: that's a BIG reduction if you subsequently do spatial comparisons with relatively-complex polygons and multiple (spatial and non-spatial) `JOIN`s.

The `property` table has relatively few columns, so I can identify which elements of the data have changes as follows:

```
-- 2nd query
create table vm201512.property_d_changes as 
select pfi, 
   case when a.view_pfi=b.view_pfi then 0::int else 1::INT end as view_pfi,
   case when a.status=b.status then 0::int else 1::INT end as status,
   case when a.property_type=b.property_type then 0::int else 1::INT end as property_type,
   -- ... more columns
from vm201512.property_d a -- table created with first query
join vm201412.property b using (pfi);
```

This gives me a nice table where I can determine precisely what changes happened to a changed (not new) row. I can figure out that `pfi` 123456 had changes to its `propnum` and its `status`; I can figure out how many `pfi` had changes to their `view_pfi` - that sort of thing.

Several of the other tables have >50 columns, which makes the case statement unwieldy (I realise it only has to be coded once, but what if the data structure changes?)

#### Question

With two rows in 2 different tables `new.table1, old.table1` where `new.table1.pfi = old.table1.pfi` and one or more columns different, is there a parsimonious, elegant PostgreSQL statement to figure out the changed columns? Or am I stuck with `CASE`?

I realise I could write a dynamic function to loop through all columns for a given table, and build the query with `CASE` statements.

Comment: Do you have any NULL values. If yes, where exactly? Do you need the result to display `0` / `1` or is actual `boolean` just as good? Currently, your `CASE` maps `NULL` in the result to `1`. Intended? Or just not applicable?

Comment: In my tables numeric data almost always takes `0` (and text types take `''`) when NULL is semantically appropriate (e.g., if an address has no `unit_number` but has a `street_number`, setting unit_number to `0` is semantically wrong). The table mentioned above is like this (so no risk of testing `NULL=NULL`, which would return `1` inappropriately), but tables that have `NULL` would need to `coalesce` to use the same code. `boolean` would be just as good as `0`/`1` (I think I just need to change `sum(col1)` to `sum(col1::int)` to get the number of rows where `col1` changed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Clarifications

[Your comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129265/postgresql-find-changed-columns-for-known-near-identical-rows-across-tables?noredirect=1#comment241612_129265) needs addressing first:

> numeric data almost always takes 0 (and text types take '')

The key word here is ***"almost"***. As long as it is not *"never"* (as in *"never ever!"*), you need to take NULL into account anyway.

> no risk of testing `NULL=NULL`, which would return 1 inappropriately

No it wouldn't. Anything compared to NULL is always NULL even `NULL=NULL`. Try it. You *need* to understand NULL comparison.

> I think I just need to change `sum(col1)` to `sum(col1::int)` to get the number of rows where `col1` changed.

If you want to count every case of `a.col1 IS DISTINCT FROM b.col1`, then you need to work with [NULL-safe comparison](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) to begin with. Apart from that, your expression would work. There are many alternatives, depending on the situation:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)

You use `select a.* into vm201512 ...` in your 1st query. Don't. `SELECT INTO ...` is discouraged. Use the superior `CREATE TABLE AS ...` like in your 2nd query. See

- [Creating temporary tables in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15700736/939860)

Postgres provides pivot functionality in the [tablefunc module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860), but nothing is pivoted here.

The core problem is the dynamic nature of the query due to varying input tables.

#### Solution

Assuming **no NULL values**. Where NULL values are possible, use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` instead of `=`.
Tested in Postgres 9.5. Should work for Postgres 9.1 or later.

You can build your queries like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_build_query(_t1 regclass
                                       , _t2 regclass
                                       , _join_col text = 'pfi')
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT format('SELECT %I, %s FROM %s a JOIN %s b USING (%1$I);'
            , _join_col
            , string_agg(format('a.%1$I = b.%1$I AS %1$I', attname), ', ' ORDER BY attnum)
            , _t1, _t2)
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = _t1        -- compare all columns from 1st table
AND    NOT attisdropped      -- no dropped (dead) columns
AND    attnum > 0            -- no system columns
AND    attname <> _join_col  -- exclude 'pfi'
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_build_query('vm201512.property_d', 'vm201412.property');
```

Returns a query like this (which you can execute in turn):

```
SELECT pfi, a.a = b.a AS a, a."weird NaMe" = b."weird NaMe" AS "weird NaMe"  -- more ...
FROM vm201512.property_d a JOIN vm201412.property b USING (pfi);
```

Result:

```
 pfi | a | b | weird NaMe
-----+---+---+------------
   1 | t | f | t
   2 | f | t | f
```

Works for *arbitrary* input tables, and deals with identifiers safely. You can optionally schema-qualify passed table names. See:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)

#### Simple dynamic solution

The difficulty is to return varying row types. SQL demands to know the return type at call time. To avoid difficulties, you could return a simple **array** instead. You get values in the original order of columns, but you don't get column names like in the first query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_diff_matrix(_t1 regclass
                                       , _t2 regclass
                                       , _join_col text = 'pfi')
  RETURNS TABLE (pfi int, change_matrix bool[])  -- adapt type of pfi as needed
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE (
   SELECT format('SELECT %I, ARRAY[%s] FROM %s a JOIN %s b USING (%1$I)'
               , _join_col
               , string_agg(format('a.%1$I = b.%1$I', attname), ', ' ORDER BY attnum)
               , _t1, _t2)
   FROM   pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = _t1        -- compare all columns from 1st table
   AND    NOT attisdropped      -- no dropped (dead) columns
   AND    attnum > 0            -- no system columns
   AND    attname <> _join_col  -- exclude 'pfi'
   );
END
$func$;
```

Call (note the difference!):

```
SELECT * FROM f_diff_matrix('vm201512.property_d', 'vm201412.property');
```

Result:

```
 pfi | change_matrix
-----+---------------
   1 | {t,f,t}  -- one element per column
   2 | {f,t,f}
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=4c39e39587a0a0b7fe0409386baf114c)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/12eaaa/1)</sub>

---

You *could* even make the same function return a dynamic result set for various tables, but I doubt it's worth the complication:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751557/939860)

If your really need dynamic pivot functionality (not in this case):

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15514334/939860)

Comment: That `f_build_query` and `f_diff_matrix` are **spectacular** pieces of coding, and they can be adapted to other use-cases in my work - I can see adaptations that will enable me to replace several existing, kludgy, functions. I have no idea why I wrote `NULL=NULL` would return `1`: that was pure typing-without-thinking-properly.

Comment: One minor thing - which may be a version issue: I had to repeat `attname` 3 times in `string_agg(format ('a.%I = b.%I AS %I', attname), ', ' ORDER BY attnum)` to stop `format` from throwing 'too few arguments' error; i.e., changed it to `string_agg(format ('a.%I = b.%I AS %I', attname, attname, attname), ', ' ORDER BY attnum)` and then it worked perfectly.

Comment: That was an oversight. It's correct in the second function and in the fiddle. To refer to parameter out of order or repeatedly in `format()`, add a position to the reference: `%1$I` instead of just `%I`. Consider the update.

Comment: This really is one of those **"Wish I could +100"** answers. With very minimal tailoring, I now call this function from a script that iterates through my each `_d` tables (for six different 'underlying' tables: `property`, `address`, `parcel` etc) and evaluates the causes of the change for each matched `pfi`. The only 'tailoring' was to change `attname <>` to `attname not in` and use a *set* of columns where changes are purely administrative (i.e., do not involve a change to zoning or boundaries). The resulting script is 25% faster than the `CASE` version, too.

Answer (score 3):

In general SQL isn't great at treating fields in columns like sets. Especially PostgreSQL, which lacks any kind of generic pivot/unpivot functionality.

Since you're on 9.3.x I'd use hstore. Performance may be less than stellar.

Simplest form:

```
test=# CREATE TABLE t1 (pfi integer, a text, b text);
CREATE TABLE
test=# CREATE TABLE t2 (pfi integer, a text, b text);
CREATE TABLE
test=# insert into t1(pfi, a, b) values (1, 'a', 'b');
INSERT 0 1
test=# insert into t2(pfi, a, b) values (1, 'a', 'z');
INSERT 0 1

test=# select hstore(t1) - hstore(t2), hstore(t2) - hstore(t1) from t1 inner join t2 on (t1.pfi = t2.pfi);
 ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------
 "b"=>"b" | "b"=>"z"
(1 row)
```

More sophisticated, using hstore only as a hack to "pivot" a single row into key/value pairs:

```
select
  t1.pfi,
  t1h."key",
  t1h."value" AS oldval,
  t2h."value" AS newval
from t1
  inner join t2 on (t1.pfi = t2.pfi)
  cross join lateral each(hstore(t1)) t1h
  inner join lateral each(hstore(t2)) t2h on (t1h."key" = t2h."key") 
where t1h."value" <> t2h."value";

 pfi | key | oldval | newval 
-----+-----+--------+--------
   1 | b   | b      | z
```

On 9.4 I'd probably use jsonb instead, but the effect is much the same.

A `row_each` function that returned text representations of each identifier and value would be handy to have built-in to save on the conversions, really.

Comment: `hstore` worked nicely, although the resulting output was slightly unwieldy (although still usable with additional processing). Downside is that it took 6x as long to perform as the `CASE` version, but that sounds worse than it is, given that it was 24sec vs <4sec. It also accounts nicely for changes in data structure (I checked by changing one column's name in one table; it showed me that all values had changed for that column in both 'directions').

Comment: I accepted this answer even though it has serious pitfalls for my specific use-case, where tables often have one column that is a WKB polygon. That seriously upends the results since sometimes the geometry changes from clockwise to counter-clockwise (no idea why: they are property and administrative boundaries, which have no clockwiseness), which results in the WKB being different despite the geometry being spatially-identical. I didn't mention that in the question, and it's a very narrow class of problem. I think I need to make some geometry-free `VIEW`s (and no `id` column).

Comment: Yeah, that's going to pretty much require you to generate queries from `information_schema` and `EXECUTE` them in plpgsql, since you need type-aware comparison semantics.

Comment: While Postgres does have pivot functionality - as I am sure you know - the question does not seem to involve pivoting per se. It's just one possible tool to solve the problem.