# About count and or null

Tags: mysql

I am practising my MySQL in Leetcode and I've encountered [this question](https://leetcode.com/problems/trips-and-users/):

> The `Trips` table holds all taxi trips. Each trip has a unique Id, while Client_Id and Driver_Id are both foreign keys to the Users_Id at the `Users` table. Status is an ENUM type of (‘completed’, ‘cancelled_by_driver’, ‘cancelled_by_client’).
>
> ```
> +----+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------------+----------+
> | Id | Client_Id | Driver_Id | City_Id |        Status      |Request_at|
> +----+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------------+----------+
> | 1  |     1     |    10     |    1    |     completed      |2013-10-01|
> | 2  |     2     |    11     |    1    | cancelled_by_driver|2013-10-01|
> | 3  |     3     |    12     |    6    |     completed      |2013-10-01|
> | 4  |     4     |    13     |    6    | cancelled_by_client|2013-10-01|
> | 5  |     1     |    10     |    1    |     completed      |2013-10-02|
> | 6  |     2     |    11     |    6    |     completed      |2013-10-02|
> | 7  |     3     |    12     |    6    |     completed      |2013-10-02|
> | 8  |     2     |    12     |    12   |     completed      |2013-10-03|
> | 9  |     3     |    10     |    12   |     completed      |2013-10-03| 
> | 10 |     4     |    13     |    12   | cancelled_by_driver|2013-10-03|
> +----+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------------+----------+
> ```
>
> The `Users` table holds all users. Each user has an unique Users_Id, and Role is an ENUM type of (‘client’, ‘driver’, ‘partner’).
>
> ```
> +----------+--------+--------+
> | Users_Id | Banned |  Role  |
> +----------+--------+--------+
> |    1     |   No   | client |
> |    2     |   Yes  | client |
> |    3     |   No   | client |
> |    4     |   No   | client |
> |    10    |   No   | driver |
> |    11    |   No   | driver |
> |    12    |   No   | driver |
> |    13    |   No   | driver |
> +----------+--------+--------+
> ```
>
> Write a SQL query to find the cancellation rate of requests made by unbanned clients between **Oct 1, 2013** and **Oct 3, 2013**. For the above tables, your SQL query should return the following rows with the cancellation rate being rounded to two decimal places.
>
> ```
> +------------+-------------------+
> |     Day    | Cancellation Rate |
> +------------+-------------------+
> | 2013-10-01 |       0.33        |
> | 2013-10-02 |       0.00        |
> | 2013-10-03 |       0.50        |
> +------------+-------------------+
> ```

I have found a solution in the question's Discuss section, here it is:

```
select t.Request_at as Day, round(count(t.Status = 'completed' or null)/count(t.Status), 2) AS `Cancellation Rate`
from 
Trips as t,
Users as u
where u.Users_Id = t.Client_Id
and u.Banned = 'No'
and t.Request_at between '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-03'
group by t.Request_at;
```

That is fine. But I want to change it to this:

```
select t.Request_at as Day, round(count(t.Status = 'completed')/count(t.Status), 2) AS `Cancellation Rate`
from 
Trips as t,
Users as u
where u.Users_Id = t.Client_Id
and u.Banned = 'No'
and t.Request_at between '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-03'
group by t.Request_at;
```

and I get the wrong answer.

I don't understand what the `or null` is used for. Is it necessary? If so, why?

Comment: There is a good answer [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27572/55596) as well.

Comment: Explained in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5011311/297408 "Why do I need “OR NULL” in MySQL when counting rows with a condition").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/59602

The explanation - `COUNT(<expr>)` counts all non-NULL values. Comparison operators return boolean values 1(=true) or 0(=false) and both are non-NULL so both would be counted by `COUNT()`. When you add the `or NULL` part, the entire expression is still `1` for *true* but becomes `NULL` when the comparison returns false (because of the ternary logic definition used in SQL). So the `COUNT()` only count *"trues"*.

Thats for standard SQL. In MySQL you can use a different trick. Because *true* and *false* are actually 1 and 0, you can just `sum(t.Status = 'completed')` to get the right number without using NULLs.