# Row number with reset in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, cte, window-functions

I have this data set in PostgreSQL:

```
    User_id    |            date         | is_cleared |
---------------+-------------------------+------------+
             C | 2016-08-03 18:28:38.37  |          1 |
             A | 2016-08-01 19:59:36.548 |          0 |
             A | 2016-08-01 23:38:29.912 |          0 |
             A | 2016-08-04 19:03:30.585 |          0 |
             A | 2016-08-08 19:53:20.251 |          0 |
             A | 2016-08-11 21:00:16.075 |          0 |
             A | 2016-08-13 21:07:01.336 |          0 |
             A | 2016-08-15 10:17:32.746 |          0 |
             A | 2016-08-17 11:54:16.75  |          0 |
             A | 2016-08-18 21:12:22.717 |          0 |
             A | 2016-08-21 19:59:26.441 |          0 |
             A | 2016-08-22 17:19:42.215 |          0 |
             A | 2016-08-24 20:18:45.516 |          1 |
             A | 2016-08-27 13:22:33.98  |          1 |
             A | 2016-08-31 16:09:25.756 |          0 |
             B | 2016-08-03 21:10:32.945 |          1 |
             B | 2016-08-05 20:40:55.644 |          1 |
             B | 2016-08-06 10:59:00.796 |          1 |
             B | 2016-08-09 22:36:50.674 |          0 |
             B | 2016-08-11 09:37:21.29  |          1 |
             B | 2016-08-13 10:15:15.858 |          1 |
             B | 2016-08-26 09:56:48.937 |          1 |
             B | 2016-08-29 09:34:13.96  |          1 |
```

And I need an output like this:

```
    User_id    |            date         | is_cleared |  custom_rank   
---------------+-------------------------+------------+---------
             C | 2016-08-03 18:28:38.37  |          1 |  1
             A | 2016-08-01 19:59:36.548 |          0 |  1
             A | 2016-08-01 23:38:29.912 |          0 |  2
             A | 2016-08-04 19:03:30.585 |          0 |  3
             A | 2016-08-08 19:53:20.251 |          0 |  4
             A | 2016-08-11 21:00:16.075 |          0 |  5
             A | 2016-08-13 21:07:01.336 |          0 |  6
             A | 2016-08-15 10:17:32.746 |          0 |  7
             A | 2016-08-17 11:54:16.75  |          0 |  8
             A | 2016-08-18 21:12:22.717 |          0 |  9
             A | 2016-08-21 19:59:26.441 |          0 |  10
             A | 2016-08-22 17:19:42.215 |          0 |  11
             A | 2016-08-24 20:18:45.516 |          1 |  12
             A | 2016-08-27 13:22:33.98  |          1 |  1
             A | 2016-08-31 16:09:25.756 |          0 |  1
             B | 2016-08-03 21:10:32.945 |          1 |  1
             B | 2016-08-05 20:40:55.644 |          1 |  1
             B | 2016-08-06 10:59:00.796 |          1 |  1
             B | 2016-08-09 22:36:50.674 |          0 |  1
             B | 2016-08-11 09:37:21.29  |          1 |  2
             B | 2016-08-13 10:15:15.858 |          1 |  1
             B | 2016-08-26 09:56:48.937 |          1 |  1
             B | 2016-08-29 09:34:13.96  |          1 |  1
```

Basically my goal is to count the number of zeros including the 1st occurrence of "1" after the zeros in the **`is_cleared`** flag.

The data is sorted by `date` and should also be partitioned by `user_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window functions and a single subquery:

```
SELECT user_id, date, is_cleared
     , count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, grp ORDER BY date) AS custom_rank
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id, date, is_cleared
        , count(is_cleared = 1 OR NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date DESC) AS grp
   FROM   tbl
   ) t
ORDER  BY user_id, date;
```

The special difficulty here: each partition *ends* with `1`. In most similar cases, each partition would *start* with `1`. The simple solution is to count occurrences of `1` in descending order. This way each partition includes the next `1` if it exists. Voilá.

Assuming all involved columns to be `NOT NULL` and `(user_id, date)` unique.

Basics:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)

Asides:

- The first row of `B` gets `custom_rank = 1`. Not `2`.
- The column `is_cleared` should really be `boolean`.
- A `timestamp` column shouldn't be called "date".

Comment: count(is_cleared = 1 OR NULL) approach is the new thing I learned today! thank you again!

Comment: @Kugutsumen: A comprehensive overview of related techniques: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572