# How can I assign group IDs depending on content?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have the following table with data as shown below; `linenr`s are monotonically increasing but not necessarily consecutive; when the `key` field contains an ellipsis `...` that indicates an entry that is continued from above:

```
create table source (
  linenr    integer unique not null,
  key       text not null,
  value     text );

insert into source values
  (  2, 'tags',  'a'          ),
  (  3, '...',   'b'          ),
  (  4, 'title', 'The Title'  ),
  (  5, 'note',  'this is'    ),
  (  6, '...',   'an EXAMPLE' ),
  (  8, 'title', 'over'       ),
  (  9, '...',   'three'      ),
  ( 10, '...',   'lines'      ),
  ( 11, 'about', 'grouping'   );
```

Now I want to have a view where a group number is assigned based on the content of the `key` field; group numbers do not have to be consecutive but should be distinct for each group of rows that starts with a key other than `...` and continues thru all lines where `key` is `...`, like this:

```
╔════════╤═══════╤═══════╤════════════╗
║ linenr │ group │  key  │   value    ║
╠════════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════════╣
║      2 │     1 │ tags  │ a          ║
║      3 │     1 │ ...   │ b          ║
║      4 │     2 │ title │ The Title  ║
║      5 │     3 │ note  │ this is    ║
║      6 │     3 │ ...   │ an EXAMPLE ║
║      8 │     4 │ title │ over       ║
║      9 │     4 │ ...   │ three      ║
║     10 │     4 │ ...   │ lines      ║
║     11 │     5 │ about │ grouping   ║
╚════════╧═══════╧═══════╧════════════╝
```

I tried to do this with windows / partitions and the tabibitosan pattern, but haven't been able to come up with anything working; also, using at the preceding row with `lag()` doesn't help where there are multiple consecutive lines with `...`. In a spreadsheet this is an extremely easy thing to do but in SQL I can seemingly not refer to the previous row of the *current* query, can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> create table source (
>   linenr    integer unique not null,
>   key       text not null,
>   value     text );
>
> insert into source values
>   (  2, 'tags',  'a'          ),
>   (  3, '...',   'b'          ),
>   (  4, 'title', 'The Title'  ),
>   (  5, 'note',  'this is'    ),
>   (  6, '...',   'an EXAMPLE' ),
>   (  8, 'title', 'over'       ),
>   (  9, '...',   'three'      ),
>   ( 10, '...',   'lines'      ),
>   ( 11, 'about', 'grouping'   );
> ```

You can get it using a simple CASE.

> ```
> select linenr, key, value,
>        case when key <> '...' then 1 end as rst
> from   source;
> ```
>
> ```
> linenr | key   | value      |  rst
> -----: | :---- | :--------- | ---:
>      2 | tags  | a          |    1
>      3 | ...   | b          | null
>      4 | title | The Title  |    1
>      5 | note  | this is    |    1
>      6 | ...   | an EXAMPLE | null
>      8 | title | over       |    1
>      9 | ...   | three      | null
>     10 | ...   | lines      | null
>     11 | about | grouping   |    1
> ```

Now SUM(rst) ignores null values and do the trick.

> ```
> select linenr, key, value,
>        sum(rst) over (order by linenr) grp
> from (
>       select linenr, key, value,
>              case when key <> '...' then 1 end as rst
>       from   source
>      ) x;
> ```
>
> ```
> linenr | key   | value      | grp
> -----: | :---- | :--------- | --:
>      2 | tags  | a          |   1
>      3 | ...   | b          |   1
>      4 | title | The Title  |   2
>      5 | note  | this is    |   3
>      6 | ...   | an EXAMPLE |   3
>      8 | title | over       |   4
>      9 | ...   | three      |   4
>     10 | ...   | lines      |   4
>     11 | about | grouping   |   5
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=dee03c419c3abf49be51ce977aa3632e)*

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Cheaper and simpler with a single window function:

```
SELECT *
     , count(key <> '...' OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY linenr) AS grp
FROM   source;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a0abf657fb1792455b950b3392c523d2)*

Related:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)
- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)

Comment: !!! this. To be sure, the accepted solution is probably more instructive to the neophyte; OTOH the lazy evaluation part of `key != '...' or null` is something useful to keep in mind. Problem solved with a crisp, performant one-liner, what's not to like?