# How to conditionally append rows to a result set?

Tags: postgresql

I have a complex `SELECT` query table that identifies relationship between `event_id` and `attribute`. Here is a simplification with a `VALUES` expression:

```
SELECT event_id, attribute
FROM (
  VALUES
    (1, '2D'),
    (1, 'IMAX'),
    (2, 'IMAX'),
    (3, '3D')
) event_attribute (event_id, attribute)
```

I want to include an extra `(event_id, '2D')` record for every `event_id` that is not already associated with a `3D` or `2D` attribute. How to conditionally append rows to a result set?

In case of the above table, the expected result would be:

```
(1, '2D'),
(1, 'IMAX'),
(2, 'IMAX'),
(2, '2D'),
(3, '3D')
```

There is also a table `event` with one row for each relevant `id`.

Comment: Complex query. I don't mind disclosing the full version of the query. However, long queries scare of people. I think it makes sense to extract the essence of the question. Here is the query that I ended up with https://gist.github.com/gajus/a803c6ade49971ccc117da5dec4151c7.

Comment: Sure. It makes a difference for the best solution, though. Is there a separate table with all relevant, unique `event_id`, like `event`?

Comment: Yes, `event` table with `id` exists.

Comment: And I assume you mean "for every event_id that is not already associated with 3D **or 2D** attribute"? Your expected result suggests as much.

Comment: That is correct. Oversight. I have updated the question.

Comment: Damned, now my answers are wrong. Should have seen that one coming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming (like was added later) a separate table `event` with all relevant unique `id` - this helps performance a bit:

```
WITH cte(event_id, attribute) AS (
   -- big SELECT query goes here instead of the VALUES expression
   VALUES
    (1, '2D'),
    (1, 'IMAX'),
    (2, 'IMAX'),
    (3, '3D')
   )
TABLE cte
UNION ALL
SELECT e.id, '2D'
FROM   event e
LEFT   JOIN cte ON cte.event_id = e.id
               AND cte.attribute IN ('2D','3D')
WHERE  cte.event_id IS NULL;
```

Related:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from-in-psql/30276023#30276023)

If your query only returns a subset of all `event_id`, you can't use the table `event` to simplify like this. Alternative without table `event`:

```
WITH cte AS (
   -- big SELECT query goes here instead of the VALUES expression
   VALUES
    (1, '2D'),
    (1, 'IMAX'),
    (2, 'IMAX'),
    (3, '3D')
   )
TABLE cte
UNION ALL
SELECT event_id, '2D'
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY 1
HAVING count(*) FILTER (WHERE attribute IN ('2D', '3D')) = 0;
```

This is somewhat similar to what you answered yourself, just shorter and a bit faster. In particular the aggregate `FILTER` clause should be instrumental. Related:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)

Since there are no indexes on the derived table from the CTE, the second query may be faster to begin with.

Comment: I don't recognize the syntax of `TABLE cte`. What is that doing?

Comment: @Noumenon: Short for `SELECT * FROM cte`. I added a link to explain above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from-in-psql/30276023#30276023

Answer (score 2):

cfr. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/82868/6

```
create table t as SELECT
  event_attribute.event_id,
  event_attribute.attribute
FROM (
  VALUES
    (1, '2D'),
    (1, 'IMAX'),
    (2, 'IMAX'),
    (3, '3D')
) event_attribute (event_id, attribute);


select E, '2D' a from (
  select distinct event_id E from t
   where not exists (
     select null from t t1
      where t1.event_id = t.event_id and t1.attribute = '3D')) X;
```

Probably faster for larger datasets:

```
select E, '2D' a from (
  select distinct event_id E from t
  except
  select distinct event_id E from t
   where attribute = '3D') T2;
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/82868/14

As, per the edited question, it's better to avoid duplicate '2D' entries, "attribute = '3D'" should be replaced by "attribute in ('3D','2D')".

Answer (score 2):

For the record, this is what I have come up with:

```
WITH
  event_attribute AS
  (
    SELECT
      event_attribute.event_id,
      event_attribute.attribute
    FROM (
      VALUES
        (1, '2D'),
        (1, 'IMAX'),
        (2, 'IMAX'),
        (3, '3D')
    ) event_attribute (event_id, attribute)
  ),
  append_attribute_event AS
  (
    SELECT event_id
    FROM event_attribute
    GROUP BY event_id
    HAVING
      MAX(CASE "attribute" WHEN '2D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND
      MAX(CASE "attribute" WHEN '3D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
  )
SELECT * FROM event_attribute
UNION ALL
SELECT event_id, '2D' "attribute"
FROM append_attribute_event
```

However, I am pretty sure [Gerard's suggestion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206589/12663) is better.

Answer (score 1):

A straight forward solution would be:

```
select event_id, attribute
from event_attribute
union all
select event_id, '2D' 
from event_attribute t1 
where not exists (
    select 1 from event_attribute t2 
    where t1.event_id = t2.event_id 
      and t2.attribute in ('2D','3D')
);
```