# Why is count(x.*) slower than count(*)?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, count

```
explain select count(x.*) from customer x;
...
->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=27005.45..27005.46 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on customer x  (cost=0.00..26412.56 rows=237156 width=994)
```

---

```
explain select count(*) from customer x;
...                                     

->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=27005.45..27005.46 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on customer x  (cost=0.00..26412.56 rows=237156 width=0)
```

---

The `COUNT(x.*)` here makes the `width` in the explain result read unnecessary row data.

I thought they should be identical, but it seems not, why?

Comment: Because Postgres doesn't optimize the expression `x.*` away and checks for each and every row whether it's null or not: See e.g.  here: https://blog.jooq.org/2019/09/19/whats-faster-count-or-count1/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is it too hard to optimize such query or they just have not do it ?

Comment: It seems to be a matter of "nobody cared": https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/df354b76-a645-73fc-9645-4508e5291d71%40gmx.net

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you should post your comment as an answer, because that's what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically, both are identical - because `x.*` always counts, even when all columns are `NULL`.
But Postgres has a **separate implementation for `count(*)`**.

It does not bother with any expression at all and only considers the existence of live rows. That's slightly faster, which sums up to a relevant difference over many rows.
The performance penalty for `count(x.*)` grows with the number of columns / width of rows, and will be rather substantial for wide rows like yours (`width=994`).

It's even [documented explicitly](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE):

> `count` ( `*` ) → `bigint`
>
> Computes the number of input rows.
>
> ---
>
> `count` ( `"any"` ) → `bigint`
>
> Computes the number of input rows in which the input value is not
> null.

The gist of it: whenever you don't care whether an expression is `NULL`, use `count(*)` instead.

Related:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)

Some other RDBMS do not have the same fast path for `count(*)`. OTOH, counting all rows in a table is comparatively slow in Postgres due to its MVCC model that forces checking row visibility. See:

- [Fast way to discover the row count of a table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945274/939860)